# How can I partition (split up, divide) a list based on a condition?

Tags: python, list

I have some code like:

```
good = [x for x in mylist if x in goodvals]
bad = [x for x in mylist if x not in goodvals]
```

The goal is to split up the contents of `mylist` into two other lists, based on whether or not they meet a condition.

How can I do this more elegantly? Can I avoid doing two separate iterations over `mylist`? Can I improve performance by doing so?

Comment: landed here looking for a way to have a condition in the set builder statement, your question answered my question :)

Comment: *split* is an unfortunate description of this operation, since it already has a specific meaning with respect to Python strings. I think *divide* is a more precise (or at least less overloaded in the context of Python iterables) word to describe this operation. I landed here looking for a list equivalent of `str.split()`, to _split_ the list into an ordered collection of consecutive sub-lists. E.g. `split([1,2,3,4,5,3,6], 3) -> ([1,2],[4,5],[6])`, as opposed to _dividing_ a list's elements by category.

Comment: [Discussion](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/engine?do=post_view_flat;post=1065226;page=1;mh=-1;list=python;sb=post_latest_reply;so=ASC) of the same topic on python-list.

Comment: IMAGE_TYPES should be a set instead of a tuple: `IMAGE_TYPES = set('.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.bmp','.png')`. n(1) instead of n(o/2), with practically no difference in readability.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

> ```
> good = [x for x in mylist if x in goodvals]
> bad  = [x for x in mylist if x not in goodvals]
> ```
>
> is there a more elegant way to do this?

That code is perfectly readable, and extremely clear!

```
# files looks like: [ ('file1.jpg', 33L, '.jpg'), ('file2.avi', 999L, '.avi'), ... ]
IMAGE_TYPES = ('.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.bmp','.png')
images = [f for f in files if f[2].lower() in IMAGE_TYPES]
anims  = [f for f in files if f[2].lower() not in IMAGE_TYPES]
```

Again, this is *fine!*

There might be slight performance improvements using sets, but it's a trivial difference, and I find the list comprehension far easier to read, and you don't have to worry about the order being messed up, duplicates being removed as so on.

In fact, I may go another step "backward", and just use a simple for loop:

```
images, anims = [], []

for f in files:
    if f.lower() in IMAGE_TYPES:
        images.append(f)
    else:
        anims.append(f)
```

The a list-comprehension or using `set()` is fine until you need to add some other check or another bit of logic - say you want to remove all 0-byte jpeg's, you just add something like..

```
if f[1] == 0:
    continue
```

Comment: Isn't there a list comprehension way without having to loop through the list twice?

Comment: @balki no sensible way that I can think of. Why'd you ask?

Comment: The problem is that this violates the DRY principle. It'd be nice if there was a better way to do this.

Comment: Once the appetite for functional programming (Haskell), or functional style (LINQ) is raised, we start to smell Python for its age - `[x for x in blah if ...]` - verbose, `lambda` is clumsy and limited... It feels like driving the coolest car from 1995 today. Not the same as back then.

Comment: That simple for-loop should be a built-in function, encouraging people to run **2** list-comprehensions in an obvious task for no reason other than python lacking a function for this is a terrible idea imho.

Comment: @TomaszGandor FTR, Haskell is _older_ than Python (and actually influenced its design). I think the syntax for list comprehension and lambdas was deliberately kept a bit on the verbose side, perhaps to discourage over-using them. Which is indeed a bit of a risk... as much as I like Haskell, I can see why many people find Python generally more readable.

Comment: A more elegant, but not performant way to do this is to actually use groupby, because that's exactly what you trying to do. Only you don't want to save group key.

Comment: the simple for loop is the best way to do this... a single loop, very clear and readable

Comment: The simple for loop is fastest. See the speed test [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31448772/2529619).

Comment: What's the point of only looping once? Before answering stop and think about this: Is it faster to two 100 things twice or two things a 100 times?

Comment: @vidstige: This question does say "list", but perhaps the iterable we want to use is a generator and can't be looped over twice. And on the subject of performance, doing 2 things 100 times is the same speed as doing 100 things 2 times, sure, but that's not what happens when you use a loop in a programming language. You're doing the things in the body, plus you're spending time doing instructions to manipulate the loop counters and iterable framework on every iteration. The fewer times you iterate, the faster; that's why [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) is a thing.

Comment: (This said, it seems highly unlikely the overhead of looping will make a practical difference in 99.9% of Python use cases. Readability should definitely be the concern here.)

Comment: The DRY principle shouldn't be treated like a commandment in a fundamentalist religion.

In many cases it is better to repeat oneself with a clear pattern using a common idiom in the language, rather than introducing some obscure hack, or a custom function, either or which may likely make things more difficult for readers of your code, and it certainly wastes time when you could accept the pragmatic and idiomatic solution and get on with the next task.

Answer (score 328):

Iterate manually, using the condition to select a list to which each element will be appended:

```
good, bad = [], []
for x in mylist:
    (bad, good)[x in goodvals].append(x)
```

Comment: That is incredibly ingenious! It took me a while to understand what was happening though. I'd like to know if others think this can be considered readable code or not.

Comment: @jgpaiva I'd probably use a dict with boolean keys instead to make it more readable. Implicit bool to int conversions are confusing.

Comment: `good.append(x) if x in goodvals else bad.append(x)` is more readable.

Comment: nice. or: `results = {True:[], False:[]}` and `for x in mylist: results[x in goodvals].append(x)`. Basically this is a simple version of the `partition` function [mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720151/simple-way-to-group-items-into-buckets?lq=1) by DSM.

Comment: @dansalmo Especially since you can make it a one-liner with the for-cycle, and if you wanted to append something more complicated than `x`, you can make it into one `append` only: `for x in mylist: (good if isgood(x) else bad).append(x)`

Comment: one may create the `(bad, good)` tuple outside the loop first, to avoid creating the tuple for every iteration of the loop. Well, the impact may be trivial if the `mylist` is short.

Comment: @MLister, in that case you should probably include the attribute lookup `(bad.append, good.append)`

Comment: I just did this and was hoping for a cleaner way, but after reading the other answers I think this probably is the most compact/ cleanest.

Comment: A slightly shorter variation: `(good if x in goodvals else bad).append(x)`

Comment: What a great answer.  While it's debatable whether it's good code, I think it shows true appreciation of the flexibility that Python offers (though I might argue this is borderline abuse).

Comment: This is a great answer and I'm glad I read it, but I'm also glad it's not the accepted answer.

Comment: While this might be cute, I wouldn't ever want to see something like this in production code. Nor in non-production code for that matter. It being the most upvoted answer to this question is a bit concerning.

Comment: Oneliner version (be kind with your futur you, please do not use it) : `e,o = map(list, (filter(None, _) for _ in zip(*((i,None) if i % 2 == 0 else (None,i) for i in range(10)))))`

Comment: I wouldn't allow this in my codebase.

Comment: OMG, What the... code!

Answer (score 124):

Here's the lazy iterator approach:

```
from itertools import tee

def split_on_condition(seq, condition):
    l1, l2 = tee((condition(item), item) for item in seq)
    return (i for p, i in l1 if p), (i for p, i in l2 if not p)
```

It evaluates the condition once per item and returns two generators, first yielding values from the sequence where the condition is true, the other where it's false.

Because it's lazy you can use it on any iterator, even an infinite one:

```
from itertools import count, islice

def is_prime(n):
    return n > 1 and all(n % i for i in xrange(2, n))

primes, not_primes = split_on_condition(count(), is_prime)
print("First 10 primes", list(islice(primes, 10)))
print("First 10 non-primes", list(islice(not_primes, 10)))
```

Usually though the non-lazy list returning approach is better:

```
def split_on_condition(seq, condition):
    a, b = [], []
    for item in seq:
        (a if condition(item) else b).append(item)
    return a, b
```

Edit: For your more specific usecase of splitting items into different lists by some key, heres a generic function that does that:

```
DROP_VALUE = lambda _:_
def split_by_key(seq, resultmapping, keyfunc, default=DROP_VALUE):
    """Split a sequence into lists based on a key function.

        seq - input sequence
        resultmapping - a dictionary that maps from target lists to keys that go to that list
        keyfunc - function to calculate the key of an input value
        default - the target where items that don't have a corresponding key go, by default they are dropped
    """
    result_lists = dict((key, []) for key in resultmapping)
    appenders = dict((key, result_lists[target].append) for target, keys in resultmapping.items() for key in keys)

    if default is not DROP_VALUE:
        result_lists.setdefault(default, [])
        default_action = result_lists[default].append
    else:
        default_action = DROP_VALUE

    for item in seq:
        appenders.get(keyfunc(item), default_action)(item)

    return result_lists
```

Usage:

```
def file_extension(f):
    return f[2].lower()

split_files = split_by_key(files, {'images': IMAGE_TYPES}, keyfunc=file_extension, default='anims')
print split_files['images']
print split_files['anims']
```

Comment: You're probably right that this violates the YAGNI principle. It is based on the assumption that number of different lists that things can be partitioned into will grow in the future.

Comment: It may be a lot of code but if `[ x for x in my_list if ExpensiveOperation(x) ]` takes a long time to run, you certainly don't want to do it twice!

Comment: +1 for offering multiple variations including iterator-based and a specific "in X" solution. The OP's "in goodvals" might be small, but replacing this with a very large dictionary or expensive predicate could be expensive. Also it reduces the need to write the list comprehension twice *everywhere* it's needed, thus reducing the likelihood for introducing typos/user error. Nice solution. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `tee` stores all the values between the iterators it returns, so it won't really save memory if you loop over one entire generator and then the other.

Answer (score 28):

Problem with all proposed solutions is that it will scan and apply the filtering function twice. I'd make a simple small function like this:

```py
def split_into_two_lists(lst, f):
    a = []
    b = []
    for elem in lst:
        if f(elem):
            a.append(elem)
        else:
            b.append(elem)
    return a, b
```

That way you are not processing anything twice and also are not repeating code.

Comment: I agree. I was looking for an "elegant" (i.e. here meaning short and built-in/implicit) way to do this without scanning the list twice, but this seems (without profiling) to be the way to go. Of course it would only matter anyway for large amounts of data.

Comment: IMHO, if you know a way of doing it with less cpu usage (and thus less power drain), there is no reason not to use it.

Comment: @winden ...Porting all my Python to C. ;)

Answer (score 19):

My take on it. I propose a lazy, single-pass, `partition` function,
which preserves relative order in the output subsequences.

### 1. Requirements

I assume that the requirements are:

- maintain elements' relative order (hence, no sets and
  dictionaries)
- evaluate condition only once for every element (hence not using
  (`i`)`filter` or `groupby`)
- allow for lazy consumption of either sequence (if we can afford to
  precompute them, then the naïve implementation is likely to be
  acceptable too)

### 2. `split` library

My `partition` function (introduced below) and other similar functions
have made it into a small library:

- [python-split](https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-split)

It's installable normally via PyPI:

```
pip install --user split
```

To split a list base on condition, use `partition` function:

```
>>> from split import partition
>>> files = [ ('file1.jpg', 33L, '.jpg'), ('file2.avi', 999L, '.avi') ]
>>> image_types = ('.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.bmp','.png')
>>> images, other = partition(lambda f: f[-1] in image_types, files)
>>> list(images)
[('file1.jpg', 33L, '.jpg')]
>>> list(other)
[('file2.avi', 999L, '.avi')]
```

### 3. `partition` function explained

Internally we need to build two subsequences at once, so consuming
only one output sequence will force the other one to be computed
too. And we need to keep state between user requests (store processed
but not yet requested elements). To keep state, I use two double-ended
queues (`deques`):

```
from collections import deque
```

`SplitSeq` class takes care of the housekeeping:

```
class SplitSeq:
    def __init__(self, condition, sequence):
        self.cond = condition
        self.goods = deque([])
        self.bads = deque([])
        self.seq = iter(sequence)
```

Magic happens in its `.getNext()` method. It is almost like `.next()`
of the iterators, but allows to specify which kind of element we want
this time. Behind the scene it doesn't discard the rejected elements,
but instead puts them in one of the two queues:

```
    def getNext(self, getGood=True):
        if getGood:
            these, those, cond = self.goods, self.bads, self.cond
        else:
            these, those, cond = self.bads, self.goods, lambda x: not self.cond(x)
        if these:
            return these.popleft()
        else:
            while 1: # exit on StopIteration
                n = self.seq.next()
                if cond(n):
                    return n
                else:
                    those.append(n)
```

The end user is supposed to use `partition` function. It takes a
condition function and a sequence (just like `map` or `filter`), and
returns two generators. The first generator builds a subsequence of
elements for which the condition holds, the second one builds the
complementary subsequence. Iterators and generators allow for lazy
splitting of even long or infinite sequences.

```
def partition(condition, sequence):
    cond = condition if condition else bool  # evaluate as bool if condition == None
    ss = SplitSeq(cond, sequence)
    def goods():
        while 1:
            yield ss.getNext(getGood=True)
    def bads():
        while 1:
            yield ss.getNext(getGood=False)
    return goods(), bads()
```

I chose the test function to be the first argument to facilitate
partial application in the future (similar to how `map` and `filter`
have the test function as the first argument).

Comment: I can still find the `split` package on PyPI, but the Bitbucket repository (which is also the project homepage link on PyPI) seems to have disappeared.

Comment: Isn't this just a simplified version of [`more_itertools.bucket`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.bucket)?

Answer (score 18):

I basically like Anders' approach as it is very general.  Here's a version that puts the categorizer first (to match filter syntax) and uses a defaultdict (assumed imported).

```
def categorize(func, seq):
    """Return mapping from categories to lists
    of categorized items.
    """
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for item in seq:
        d[func(item)].append(item)
    return d
```

Comment: I was going to try to pick out the statements from [Zen of Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) that apply here, but it's too many for a comment. =) Awesome piece of code.

Answer (score 16):

### Elegant and Fast

Inspired by DanSalmo's comment, here is a solution that is concise, elegant, and at the same time is one of the fastest solutions.

```
good_set = set(goodvals)
good, bad = [], []
for item in my_list:
    good.append(item) if item in good_set else bad.append(item)
```

Tip: Turning `goodvals` into a set gives us an easy speed boost.

### Fastest

For maximum speed, we take the fastest answer and turbocharge it by turning good_list into a set. That alone gives us a 40%+ speed boost, and we end up with a solution that is more than 5.5x as fast as the slowest solution, even while it remains readable.

```
good_list_set = set(good_list)  # 40%+ faster than a tuple.

good, bad = [], []
for item in my_origin_list:
    if item in good_list_set:
        good.append(item)
    else:
        bad.append(item)
```

### A little shorter

This is a more concise version of the previous answer.

```
good_list_set = set(good_list)  # 40%+ faster than a tuple.

good, bad = [], []
for item in my_origin_list:
    out = good if item in good_list_set else bad
    out.append(item)
```

---

Elegance can be somewhat subjective, but some of the Rube Goldberg style solutions that are cute and ingenious are quite concerning and should not be used in production code in any language, let alone python which is elegant at heart.

---

Benchmark results:

```
filter_BJHomer                  80/s       --   -3265%   -5312%   -5900%   -6262%   -7273%   -7363%   -8051%   -8162%   -8244%
zip_Funky                       118/s    4848%       --   -3040%   -3913%   -4450%   -5951%   -6085%   -7106%   -7271%   -7393%
two_lst_tuple_JohnLaRoy         170/s   11332%    4367%       --   -1254%   -2026%   -4182%   -4375%   -5842%   -6079%   -6254%
if_else_DBR                     195/s   14392%    6428%    1434%       --    -882%   -3348%   -3568%   -5246%   -5516%   -5717%
two_lst_compr_Parand            213/s   16750%    8016%    2540%     967%       --   -2705%   -2946%   -4786%   -5083%   -5303%
if_else_1_line_DanSalmo         292/s   26668%   14696%    7189%    5033%    3707%       --    -331%   -2853%   -3260%   -3562%
tuple_if_else                   302/s   27923%   15542%    7778%    5548%    4177%     343%       --   -2609%   -3029%   -3341%
set_1_line                      409/s   41308%   24556%   14053%   11035%    9181%    3993%    3529%       --    -569%    -991%
set_shorter                     434/s   44401%   26640%   15503%   12303%   10337%    4836%    4345%     603%       --    -448%
set_if_else                     454/s   46952%   28358%   16699%   13349%   11290%    5532%    5018%    1100%     469%       --
```

The full benchmark code for Python 3.7 (modified from FunkySayu):

```
good_list = ['.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.bmp','.png']

import random
import string
my_origin_list = []
for i in range(10000):
    fname = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(random.randrange(10)))
    if random.getrandbits(1):
        fext = random.choice(list(good_list))
    else:
        fext = "." + ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(3))

    my_origin_list.append((fname + fext, random.randrange(1000), fext))

# Parand
def two_lst_compr_Parand(*_):
    return [e for e in my_origin_list if e[2] in good_list], [e for e in my_origin_list if not e[2] in good_list]

# dbr
def if_else_DBR(*_):
    a, b = list(), list()
    for e in my_origin_list:
        if e[2] in good_list:
            a.append(e)
        else:
            b.append(e)
    return a, b

# John La Rooy
def two_lst_tuple_JohnLaRoy(*_):
    a, b = list(), list()
    for e in my_origin_list:
        (b, a)[e[2] in good_list].append(e)
    return a, b

# # Ants Aasma
# def f4():
#     l1, l2 = tee((e[2] in good_list, e) for e in my_origin_list)
#     return [i for p, i in l1 if p], [i for p, i in l2 if not p]

# My personal way to do
def zip_Funky(*_):
    a, b = zip(*[(e, None) if e[2] in good_list else (None, e) for e in my_origin_list])
    return list(filter(None, a)), list(filter(None, b))

# BJ Homer
def filter_BJHomer(*_):
    return list(filter(lambda e: e[2] in good_list, my_origin_list)), list(filter(lambda e: not e[2] in good_list,                                                                             my_origin_list))

# ChaimG's answer; as a list.
def if_else_1_line_DanSalmo(*_):
    good, bad = [], []
    for e in my_origin_list:
        _ = good.append(e) if e[2] in good_list else bad.append(e)
    return good, bad

# ChaimG's answer; as a set.
def set_1_line(*_):
    good_list_set = set(good_list)
    good, bad = [], []
    for e in my_origin_list:
        _ = good.append(e) if e[2] in good_list_set else bad.append(e)
    return good, bad

# ChaimG set and if else list.
def set_shorter(*_):
    good_list_set = set(good_list)
    good, bad = [], []
    for e in my_origin_list:
        out = good if e[2] in good_list_set else bad
        out.append(e)
    return good, bad

# ChaimG's best answer; if else as a set.
def set_if_else(*_):
    good_list_set = set(good_list)
    good, bad = [], []
    for e in my_origin_list:
        if e[2] in good_list_set:
            good.append(e)
        else:
            bad.append(e)
    return good, bad

# ChaimG's best answer; if else as a set.
def tuple_if_else(*_):
    good_list_tuple = tuple(good_list)
    good, bad = [], []
    for e in my_origin_list:
        if e[2] in good_list_tuple:
            good.append(e)
        else:
            bad.append(e)
    return good, bad

def cmpthese(n=0, functions=None):
    results = {}
    for func_name in functions:
        args = ['%s(range(256))' % func_name, 'from __main__ import %s' % func_name]
        t = Timer(*args)
        results[func_name] = 1 / (t.timeit(number=n) / n) # passes/sec

    functions_sorted = sorted(functions, key=results.__getitem__)
    for f in functions_sorted:
        diff = []
        for func in functions_sorted:
            if func == f:
                diff.append("--")
            else:
                diff.append(f"{results[f]/results[func]*100 - 100:5.0%}")
        diffs = " ".join(f'{x:>8s}' for x in diff)

        print(f"{f:27s} \t{results[f]:,.0f}/s {diffs}")


if __name__=='__main__':
    from timeit import Timer
cmpthese(1000, 'two_lst_compr_Parand if_else_DBR two_lst_tuple_JohnLaRoy zip_Funky filter_BJHomer if_else_1_line_DanSalmo set_1_line set_if_else tuple_if_else set_shorter'.split(" "))
```

Comment: I'd encourage you to also test my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71985816/6153495 which in my tests gets highly competitive results while also being quite readable.

Comment: When making claims about the relative performance of algorithms, it's a good idea to study how that relative performance changes according to the input. Are some algorithms relatively better when the inputs are longer or shorter? When they contain more or fewer duplicates? When the condition being tested is more or less expensive? These sorts of factors can make a large difference even when every algorithm has the same big-O complexity.

Answer (score 14):

**First go** (pre-OP-edit): Use sets:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
goodvals = [1,3,7,8,9]

myset = set(mylist)
goodset = set(goodvals)

print list(myset.intersection(goodset))  # [1, 3, 7]
print list(myset.difference(goodset))    # [2, 4, 5, 6]
```

That's good for both readability (IMHO) and performance.

**Second go** (post-OP-edit):

Create your list of good extensions as a set:

```
IMAGE_TYPES = set(['.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.bmp','.png'])
```

and that will increase performance.  Otherwise, what you have looks fine to me.

Comment: not best solution if the lists were in some order before splitting and you need them to stay in that order.

Comment: Wouldn't that remove duplicates?

Comment: Creating a set is O(n log n).  Iterating the list twice is O(n).  The set solution may be more elegant (when it's correct in the first place) but is most certainly slower as n increases.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang Iterating the list is O(n * n). That's because each item in the list may need to be compared with each item in `goodvals`.

Comment: @ChaimG good point, although we also need to consider the cost of the intersection and difference operations (which I do not know off hand but I'm pretty sure they're superlinear as well).

Comment: Ah- good vision; create one set and then iterate the other list by checking set membership! :)

Answer (score 13):

[itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) almost does what you want, except it requires the items to be sorted to ensure that you get a single contiguous range, so you need to sort by your key first (otherwise you'll get multiple interleaved groups for each type).  eg.

```
def is_good(f):
    return f[2].lower() in IMAGE_TYPES

files = [ ('file1.jpg', 33L, '.jpg'), ('file2.avi', 999L, '.avi'), ('file3.gif', 123L, '.gif')]

for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(files, key=is_good), key=is_good):
    print key, list(group)
```

gives:

```
False [('file2.avi', 999L, '.avi')]
True [('file1.jpg', 33L, '.jpg'), ('file3.gif', 123L, '.gif')]
```

Similar to the other solutions, the key func can be defined to divide into any number of groups you want.

Answer (score 12):

```
good.append(x) if x in goodvals else bad.append(x)
```

This elegant and concise answer by @dansalmo showed up buried in the comments, so I'm just reposting it here as an answer so it can get the prominence it deserves, especially for new readers.

Complete example:

```
good, bad = [], []
for x in my_list:
    good.append(x) if x in goodvals else bad.append(x)
```

Comment: Or `(bad, good)[x in goodvals].append(x)`.

Answer (score 8):

```
bad = []
good = [x for x in mylist if x in goodvals or bad.append(x)]
```

append returns None, so it works.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I like the version you cited, assuming you already have a list of `goodvals` hanging around.  If not, something like:

```
good = filter(lambda x: is_good(x), mylist)
bad = filter(lambda x: not is_good(x), mylist)
```

Of course, that's really very similar to using a list comprehension like you originally did, but with a function instead of a lookup:

```
good = [x for x in mylist if is_good(x)]
bad  = [x for x in mylist if not is_good(x)]
```

In general, I find the aesthetics of list comprehensions to be very pleasing.  Of course, if you don't actually need to preserve ordering and don't need duplicates, using the `intersection` and `difference` methods on sets would work well too.

Comment: Of course, `filter(lambda x: is_good(x), mylist)` can be reduced to `filter(is_good, mylist)`

Comment: adding the extra function call actually doubles (!) the execution time, compared to the list comprehensions, from what I've seen in profiling. it's hard to beat a list comprehension, most of the time.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make it in FP style:

```
good, bad = [ sum(x, []) for x in zip(*(([y], []) if y in goodvals else ([], [y])
                                        for y in mylist)) ]
```

Not the most readable solution, but at least iterates through mylist only once.

Comment: Although it iterates through the list only once, the performance is not that good because of the list appends. Appending to a list is potentially expensive operation (when compared with deque.append for example). Actually, this solution is extremely slow when compared with other solutions in here (21.4s on 100000 random integers and testing their value).

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes, it looks like list comprehension is not the best thing to use !

I made a little test based on the answer people gave to this topic, tested on a random generated list. Here is the generation of the list (there's probably a better way to do, but it's not the point) :

```
good_list = ('.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.bmp','.png')

import random
import string
my_origin_list = []
for i in xrange(10000):
    fname = ''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for i in range(random.randrange(10)))
    if random.getrandbits(1):
        fext = random.choice(good_list)
    else:
        fext = "." + ''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for i in range(3))

    my_origin_list.append((fname + fext, random.randrange(1000), fext))
```

And here we go

```
# Parand
def f1():
    return [e for e in my_origin_list if e[2] in good_list], [e for e in my_origin_list if not e[2] in good_list]

# dbr
def f2():
    a, b = list(), list()
    for e in my_origin_list:
        if e[2] in good_list:
            a.append(e)
        else:
            b.append(e)
    return a, b

# John La Rooy
def f3():
    a, b = list(), list()
    for e in my_origin_list:
        (b, a)[e[2] in good_list].append(e)
    return a, b

# Ants Aasma
def f4():
    l1, l2 = tee((e[2] in good_list, e) for e in my_origin_list)
    return [i for p, i in l1 if p], [i for p, i in l2 if not p]

# My personal way to do
def f5():
    a, b = zip(*[(e, None) if e[2] in good_list else (None, e) for e in my_origin_list])
    return list(filter(None, a)), list(filter(None, b))

# BJ Homer
def f6():
    return filter(lambda e: e[2] in good_list, my_origin_list), filter(lambda e: not e[2] in good_list, my_origin_list)
```

Using the [cmpthese](https://gist.github.com/sekimura/660557) function, the best result is the dbr answer :

```
f1     204/s  --    -5%   -14%   -15%   -20%   -26%
f6     215/s     6%  --    -9%   -11%   -16%   -22%
f3     237/s    16%    10%  --    -2%    -7%   -14%
f4     240/s    18%    12%     2%  --    -6%   -13%
f5     255/s    25%    18%     8%     6%  --    -8%
f2     277/s    36%    29%    17%    15%     9%  --
```

Comment: Faster functions with updated benchmarks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55368810/2529619).

Answer (score 4):

```
def partition(pred, iterable):
    'Use a predicate to partition entries into false entries and true entries'
    # partition(is_odd, range(10)) --> 0 2 4 6 8   and  1 3 5 7 9
    t1, t2 = tee(iterable)
    return filterfalse(pred, t1), filter(pred, t2)
```

Check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Answer (score 4):

I think a generalization of splitting a an iterable based on N conditions is handy

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def partition(iterable,*conditions):
    '''Returns a list with the elements that satisfy each of condition.
       Conditions are assumed to be exclusive'''
    d= OrderedDict((i,list())for i in range(len(conditions)))        
    for e in iterable:
        for i,condition in enumerate(conditions):
            if condition(e):
                d[i].append(e)
                break                    
    return d.values()
```

For instance:

```
ints,floats,other = partition([2, 3.14, 1, 1.69, [], None],
                              lambda x: isinstance(x, int), 
                              lambda x: isinstance(x, float),
                              lambda x: True)

print " ints: {}\n floats:{}\n other:{}".format(ints,floats,other)

 ints: [2, 1]
 floats:[3.14, 1.69]
 other:[[], None]
```

If the element may satisfy multiple conditions, remove the break.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using an external library there two I know that nativly implement this operation:

```
>>> files = [ ('file1.jpg', 33, '.jpg'), ('file2.avi', 999, '.avi')]
>>> IMAGE_TYPES = ('.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.bmp','.png')
```

- [`iteration_utilities.partition`](http://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/partition.html):

  ```
  >>> from iteration_utilities import partition
  >>> notimages, images = partition(files, lambda x: x[2].lower() in IMAGE_TYPES)
  >>> notimages
  [('file2.avi', 999, '.avi')]
  >>> images
  [('file1.jpg', 33, '.jpg')]
  ```
- [`more_itertools.partition`](http://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.partition)

  ```
  >>> from more_itertools import partition
  >>> notimages, images = partition(lambda x: x[2].lower() in IMAGE_TYPES, files)
  >>> list(notimages)  # returns a generator so you need to explicitly convert to list.
  [('file2.avi', 999, '.avi')]
  >>> list(images)
  [('file1.jpg', 33, '.jpg')]
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @gnibbler's [great (but terse!) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12135169/182469), we can apply that approach to map to multiple partitions:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def splitter(l, mapper):
    """Split an iterable into multiple partitions generated by a callable mapper."""

    results = defaultdict(list)

    for x in l:
        results[mapper(x)] += [x]

    return results
```

Then `splitter` can then be used as follows:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 3]
>>> split = splitter(l, lambda x: x % 2 == 0)  # partition l into odds and evens
>>> split.items()
>>> [(False, [1, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3]), (True, [2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 4, 2])]
```

This works for more than two partitions with a more complicated mapping (and on iterators, too):

```
>>> import math
>>> l = xrange(1, 23)
>>> split = splitter(l, lambda x: int(math.log10(x) * 5))
>>> split.items()
[(0, [1]),
 (1, [2]),
 (2, [3]),
 (3, [4, 5, 6]),
 (4, [7, 8, 9]),
 (5, [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]),
 (6, [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22])]
```

Or using a dictionary to map:

```
>>> map = {'A': 1, 'X': 2, 'B': 3, 'Y': 1, 'C': 2, 'Z': 3}
>>> l = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'Z']
>>> split = splitter(l, map.get)
>>> split.items()
(1, ['A', 'Y', 'A']), (2, ['C', 'C', 'X']), (3, ['B', 'Z', 'Z'])]
```

Comment: ...just noticed this is basically the same as @alan-isaac has already answered.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution to this problem. I needed a solution that is as fast as possible. That means only one iteration over the list and preferably O(1) for adding data to one of the resulting lists. This is very similar to the solution provided by *sastanin*, except much shorter:

```
from collections import deque

def split(iterable, function):
    dq_true = deque()
    dq_false = deque()

    # deque - the fastest way to consume an iterator and append items
    deque((
      (dq_true if function(item) else dq_false).append(item) for item in iterable
    ), maxlen=0)

    return dq_true, dq_false
```

Then, you can use the function in the following way:

```
lower, higher = split([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], lambda x: x < 5)

selected, other = split([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], lambda x: x in {0,4,9})
```

If you're not fine with the resulting `deque` object, you can easily convert it to `list`, `set`, whatever you like (for example `list(lower)`). The conversion is much faster, that construction of the lists directly.

This methods keeps order of the items, as well as any duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

For example, splitting list by even and odd

```
arr = range(20)
even, odd = reduce(lambda res, next: res[next % 2].append(next) or res, arr, ([], []))
```

Or in general:

```
def split(predicate, iterable):
    return reduce(lambda res, e: res[predicate(e)].append(e) or res, iterable, ([], []))
```

**Advantages:**

- Shortest posible way
- Predicate applies only once for each element

**Disadvantages**

- Requires knowledge of functional programing paradigm

Answer (score 1):

## solution

```
from itertools import tee

def unpack_args(fn):
    return lambda t: fn(*t)

def separate(fn, lx):
    return map(
        unpack_args(
            lambda i, ly: filter(
                lambda el: bool(i) == fn(el),
                ly)),
        enumerate(tee(lx, 2)))
```

## test

```
[even, odd] = separate(
    lambda x: bool(x % 2),
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(list(even) == [2, 4])
print(list(odd) == [1, 3, 5])
```

Answer (score 1):

If the list is made of groups and intermittent separators, you can use:

```py
def split(items, p):
    groups = [[]]
    for i in items:
        if p(i):
            groups.append([])
        groups[-1].append(i)
    return groups
```

Usage:

```py
split(range(1,11), lambda x: x % 3 == 0)
# gives [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another answer, short but "evil" (for list-comprehension side effects).

```
digits = list(range(10))
odd = [digits.pop(i) for i, x in enumerate(digits) if x % 2]

>>> odd
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

>>> digits
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Boolean logic to assign data to two arrays

```
>>> images, anims = [[i for i in files if t ^ (i[2].lower() in IMAGE_TYPES) ] for t in (0, 1)]
>>> images
[('file1.jpg', 33, '.jpg')]
>>> anims
[('file2.avi', 999, '.avi')]
```

Answer (score 0):

For perfomance, try `itertools`.

> The [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module standardizes a core set of fast, memory efficient tools that are useful by themselves or in combination. Together, they form an “iterator algebra” making it possible to construct specialized tools succinctly and efficiently in pure Python.

See [itertools.ifilter](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) or imap.

> itertools.ifilter(predicate, iterable)
>
> Make an iterator that filters elements from iterable returning only those for which the predicate is True

Comment: ifilter/imap (and generators in general) are pretty slow... in general, in my profiling, if you take a list comprehension like `[x for x in a if x > 50000]` on a simple array of 100000 integers (via random.shuffle), `filter(lambda x: x> 50000, a)` will take 2x as long, `ifilter(lambda x: x> 50000, a); list(result)` takes about 2.3x as long. Strange but true.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on clever, you could take Winden's solution and just a bit spurious cleverness:

```
def splay(l, f, d=None):
  d = d or {}
  for x in l: d.setdefault(f(x), []).append(x)
  return d
```

Comment: The "d or {}" is a bit dangerous.  If an empty dict gets passed in, it won't be mutated in place.

Comment: True, but it gets returned, so... Actually, this is the perfect example of why you *don't* want to add more clever to your code. :-P

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you won't need that other half of the list.
For example:

```
import sys
from itertools import ifilter

trustedPeople = sys.argv[1].split(',')
newName = sys.argv[2]

myFriends = ifilter(lambda x: x.startswith('Shi'), trustedPeople)

print '%s is %smy friend.' % (newName, newName not in myFriends 'not ' or '')
```

Comment: This does not answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Already quite a few solutions here, but yet another way of doing that would be -

```
anims = []
images = [f for f in files if (lambda t: True if f[2].lower() in IMAGE_TYPES else anims.append(t) and False)(f)]
```

Iterates over the list only once, and looks a bit more pythonic and hence readable to me.

```
>>> files = [ ('file1.jpg', 33L, '.jpg'), ('file2.avi', 999L, '.avi'), ('file1.bmp', 33L, '.bmp')]
>>> IMAGE_TYPES = ('.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.bmp','.png')
>>> anims = []
>>> images = [f for f in files if (lambda t: True if f[2].lower() in IMAGE_TYPES else anims.append(t) and False)(f)]
>>> print '\n'.join([str(anims), str(images)])
[('file2.avi', 999L, '.avi')]
[('file1.jpg', 33L, '.jpg'), ('file1.bmp', 33L, '.bmp')]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a 2-pass approach, separating evaluation of the predicate from filtering the list:

```
def partition(pred, iterable):
    xs = list(zip(map(pred, iterable), iterable))
    return [x[1] for x in xs if x[0]], [x[1] for x in xs if not x[0]]
```

What's nice about this, performance-wise (in addition to evaluating `pred` only once on each member of `iterable`), is that it moves a lot of logic out of the interpreter and into highly-optimized iteration and mapping code. This can speed up iteration over long iterables, as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25881130/3408454).

Expressivity-wise, it takes advantage of expressive idioms like comprehensions and mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a good approach but it can be done in this way as well

```
IMAGE_TYPES = ('.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.bmp','.png')
files = [ ('file1.jpg', 33L, '.jpg'), ('file2.avi', 999L, '.avi')]
images, anims = reduce(lambda (i, a), f: (i + [f], a) if f[2] in IMAGE_TYPES else (i, a + [f]), files, ([], []))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
images = [f for f in files if f[2].lower() in IMAGE_TYPES]
anims  = [f for f in files if f not in images]
```

Nice when the condition is longer, such as in your example. The reader doesn't have to figure out the negative condition and whether it captures all other cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can do lazy functional programming in Python, like this:

```py
partition = lambda l, c: map(
  lambda iii: (i for ii in iii for i in ii),
  zip(*(([], [e]) if c(e) else ([e], []) for e in l)))
```

Functional programming is elegant, but not in Python. See also this example in case you know there are not `None` values in your list:

```py
partition = lambda l, c: map(
  filter(lambda x: x is not None, l),
  zip(*((None, e) if c(e) else (e, None) for e in l)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers don't seem to satisfy all four of my obsessive compulsive ticks:

1. Be as lazy as possible,
2. Evaluate the original Iterable only once
3. Evaluate the predicate only once per item
4. Provide nice type annotations (for python 3.7)

My solution isn't pretty, and I don't think I can recommend using it, but here it is:

```py
def iter_split_on_predicate(predicate: Callable[[T], bool], iterable: Iterable[T]) -> Tuple[Iterator[T], Iterator[T]]:
    deque_predicate_true = deque()
    deque_predicate_false = deque()
    
    # define a generator function to consume the input iterable
    # the Predicate is evaluated once per item, added to the appropriate deque, and the predicate result it yielded 
    def shared_generator(definitely_an_iterator):
        for item in definitely_an_iterator:
            print("Evaluate predicate.")
            if predicate(item):
                deque_predicate_true.appendleft(item)
                yield True
            else:
                deque_predicate_false.appendleft(item)
                yield False
    
    # consume input iterable only once,
    # converting to an iterator with the iter() function if necessary. Probably this conversion is unnecessary
    shared_gen = shared_generator(
        iterable if isinstance(iterable, collections.abc.Iterator) else iter(iterable)
    )
    
    # define a generator function for each predicate outcome and queue
    def iter_for(predicate_value, hold_queue):
        def consume_shared_generator_until_hold_queue_contains_something():
            if not hold_queue:
                try:
                    while next(shared_gen) != predicate_value:
                        pass
                except:
                    pass
        
        consume_shared_generator_until_hold_queue_contains_something()
        while hold_queue:
            print("Yield where predicate is "+str(predicate_value))
            yield hold_queue.pop()
            consume_shared_generator_until_hold_queue_contains_something()
    
    # return a tuple of two generators  
    return iter_for(predicate_value=True, hold_queue=deque_predicate_true), iter_for(predicate_value=False, hold_queue=deque_predicate_false)
```

Testing with the following we get the output below from the print statements:

```py
t,f = iter_split_on_predicate(lambda item:item>=10,[1,2,3,10,11,12,4,5,6,13,14,15])
print(list(zip(t,f)))
# Evaluate predicate.
# Evaluate predicate.
# Evaluate predicate.
# Evaluate predicate.
# Yield where predicate is True
# Yield where predicate is False
# Evaluate predicate.
# Yield where predicate is True
# Yield where predicate is False
# Evaluate predicate.
# Yield where predicate is True
# Yield where predicate is False
# Evaluate predicate.
# Evaluate predicate.
# Evaluate predicate.
# Evaluate predicate.
# Yield where predicate is True
# Yield where predicate is False
# Evaluate predicate.
# Yield where predicate is True
# Yield where predicate is False
# Evaluate predicate.
# Yield where predicate is True
# Yield where predicate is False
# [(10, 1), (11, 2), (12, 3), (13, 4), (14, 5), (15, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A generator based version, if you can put up with one or maybe two reversals of the original list.

A setup...

```
random.seed(1234)
a = list(range(10))
random.shuffle(a)
a
[2, 8, 3, 5, 6, 4, 9, 0, 1, 7]
```

And the split...

```
(list((a.pop(j) for j, y in [(len(a)-i-1, x) for i,x in enumerate(a[::-1])] if y%2 == 0))[::-1], a)
([2, 8, 6, 4, 0], [3, 5, 9, 1, 7])
```

1. Another list of tuples of locations and each element is built in reverse order.
2. In a generator wrapped round that each element is tested against the predicate (here test for even) and if True then the element is poped using previously computed locations.  We are working backwards along the list so poping elements out does not change positions closer to the beginning of the list.
3. A wrapping list() evaluates the generator and a final revers [::-1] puts the elements back in the right order.
4. The original list "a" now only contains elements that for which the predicate is False.

Answer (score 0):

### Clear and fast

This list comprehension is simple to read and fast. Exactly what the OP asked for.

```
set_good_vals = set(good_vals)    # Speed boost.
good = [x for x in my_list if x in set_good_vals]
bad = [x for x in my_list if x not in set_good_vals]
```

I would prefer a single list comprehension rather than two, but unlike many of the answers posted (some of which are quite ingenious) it is readable and clear. It is also one of the fastest answers on the page.

The only answer that is [slightly] faster is:

```
set_good_vals = set(good_vals)
good, bad = [], []
for item in my_list:
    _ = good.append(item) if item in set_good_vals else bad.append(item)
```

...and variations of this. (See my other answer). But I find the first way more elegant and it's almost as fast.

Answer (score 0):

I turned to `numpy` to solve this to limit lines and make into a simple function.

I was able to get a conditional met, separating a list into two, using `np.where` to separate out a list. This works for numeric, but this could be expanded using strings and lists I believe.

Here it is...

```
from numpy import where as wh, array as arr

midz = lambda a, mid: (a[wh(a > mid)], a[wh((a =< mid))])
p_ = arr([i for i in [75, 50, 403, 453, 0, 25, 428] if i])
high,low = midz(p_, p_.mean())
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple generator version, holds the least amount of values possible in memory and calls `pred` only once:

```
from collections import deque
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, Iterable
_T = TypeVar('_T')

def iter_split(pred: Callable[[_T], bool],
               iterable: Iterable[_T]) -> tuple[Iterable[_T], Iterable[_T]]:
    """Split an iterable into two iterables based on a predicate.
    
    The predicate will only be called once per element.
    
    Returns:
        A tuple of two iterables, the first containing all elements for which
        the predicate returned True, the second containing all elements for
        which the predicate returned False.
    """
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    true_values: deque[_T] = deque()
    false_values: deque[_T] = deque()
    
    def true_generator():
        while True:
            while true_values:
                yield true_values.popleft()
            
            for item in iterator:
                if pred(item):
                    yield item
                    break
                false_values.append(item)
            else:
                break
            
    def false_generator():
        while True:
            while false_values:
                yield false_values.popleft()
            
            for item in iterator:
                if not pred(item):
                    yield item
                    break
                true_values.append(item)
            else:
                break

    return true_generator(), false_generator()
```

Answer (score -1):

If your concern is not to use two lines of code for an operation whose semantics only need once you just wrap some of the approaches above (even your own) in a single function:

```
def part_with_predicate(l, pred):
    return [i for i in l if pred(i)], [i for i in l if not pred(i)]
```

It is not a lazy-eval approach and it does iterate twice through the list, but it allows you to partition the list in one line of code.

Comment: Looks like two lines of code to me.  If you mean it's only one line at the call site, that doesn't change by splitting the last line above into two.  The concern is that if executing `pred(i)` takes a long time you're doubling your wait.

Answer (score -1):

```
def partition(pred, seq):
  return reduce( lambda (yes, no), x: (yes+[x], no) if pred(x) else (yes, no+[x]), seq, ([], []) )
```

Answer (score -1):

This question has many answers already, but all seem inferior to my favorite approach to this problem, which iterates through and tests each item just once, and uses the speed of list-comprehension to build one of the two output lists, so that it only has to use the comparatively slow `append` to build one of the output lists:

```py
bad = []
good = [x for x in mylist if x in goodvals or bad.append(x)]
```

In [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71907780/6153495), I explain how this approach works (a combination of Python's greedy evaluation of `or` refraining from executing the `append` for "good" items, and `append` returning a false-like value which leaves the `if` condition false for "bad" items), and I show `timeit` results indicating that this approach outcompetes alternatives like those suggested here, especially in cases where the majority of items will go into the list built by list-comprehension (in this case, the `good` list).

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57976307/12671057) isn't inferior.

Comment: The identical answer given in 2019 deserves the upvote.