# python equivalent of filter() getting two output lists (i.e. partition of a list)

Tags: python, filter, data-partitioning

Let's say I have a list, and a filtering function. Using something like

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x > 10, [1,4,12,7,42])
[12, 42]
```

I can get the elements matching the criterion. Is there a function I could use that would output two lists, one of elements matching, one of the remaining elements? I could call the `filter()` function twice, but that's kinda ugly :)

**Edit:** the order of elements should be conserved, and I may have identical elements multiple times.

Comment: Last time I wanted this I worked with `[(pred(x), x) for x in seq]` instead.

Comment: `[(pred(x), x) for x in seq]` will give me a list like `[(True, elem1), (False, elem2), ...]`, which is not what I want, though.

Comment: You can make it with reduce function and it will be as fast as single filter.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try this:

```
def partition(pred, iterable):
    trues = []
    falses = []
    for item in iterable:
        if pred(item):
            trues.append(item)
        else:
            falses.append(item)
    return trues, falses
```

Usage:

```
>>> trues, falses = partition(lambda x: x > 10, [1,4,12,7,42])
>>> trues
[12, 42]
>>> falses
[1, 4, 7]
```

There is also an implementation suggestion in [itertools recipes](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import filterfalse, tee

def partition(pred, iterable):
    'Use a predicate to partition entries into false entries and true entries'
    # partition(is_odd, range(10)) --> 0 2 4 6 8   and  1 3 5 7 9
    t1, t2 = tee(iterable)
    return filterfalse(pred, t1), filter(pred, t2)
```

The recipe comes from the Python 3.x documentation. In Python 2.x `filterfalse` is called `ifilterfalse`.

Comment: OK, I can create my own function. But that's even longer than two calls to filter (though more efficient, of course).

Comment: Note that if you don't need to care about the order you might be better off just by using a set since it gives you difference op (ie. orig - result gives non-matching elems).

Comment: I do care about order, and I do care about possible duplicate elements.

Comment: This operation is generally called "partition". It is used in quick-sort, among others.

Comment: @MizardX: +1 For the name suggestion. I Googled it and there is actually an implementation of `partition` in itertools recipes: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

Comment: Unless you don't just want two lists, the `itertools` recipe may not be worthwhile: it makes twice as many calls to the predicate, and hence takes almost twice as long; and the code is no clearer.

Comment: Awesome partition implementation. it looks pretty simple and clear.

Comment: `(trues if pred(item) else falses).append(item)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45061735/dynamically-selecting-the-list-while-appending-the-element#comment77096817_45061735

Comment: I've written a long post below to justify my upvote. Thank you for staying simple and fast.

Comment: A possible problem with the `itertools` approach is the inherent laziness of generators, so that if the predicate involves a mutable resource (someone else has named testing the accessibility of an URL) it is possible to have an original element in both _lists_ (loosely speaking) or in no one...

Answer (score 29):

```
>>> def partition(l, p):
...     return reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0]+[y], x[1]) if p(y) else (x[0], x[1]+[y]), l,  ([], []))
... 
>>> partition([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], lambda x: x < 3)
([1, 2], [3, 4, 5])
```

and a little uglier but faster version of the above code:

```
def partition(l, p):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x[0].append(y) or x if p(y) else x[1].append(y) or x, l,  ([], []))
```

This is second edit, but I think it matters:

```
 def partition(l, p):
     return reduce(lambda x, y: x[not p(y)].append(y) or x, l, ([], []))
```

The second and the third are as quick as the iterative one upper but are less code.

Comment: Coming from the functional department, I find this solution most elegant.

Comment: @josch Do you actually find that *readable*? It's not even remotely clear what any version of that code does.

Comment: @alcalde I think it might be easier to immediately see this if you are familiar with the accumulator/fold pattern of functional languages. The very first version works just as I would write a fold_left in Ocaml for example. The `p(y)` check for a condition and will then either append the current element to the first or second list. If you don't like the `x[0]+[y]` syntax, then just use `x[0].append(y)` as in the second solution. I find the last one least desirable because it depends on a boolean (`not p(y)`) being interpreted as an integer index.

Comment: As I've written below, this is a bit an overcomplicated solution, but it's a +1 because I've fallen in love with the idiom `object.mutate() or object` — I have the greatest plans for abusing it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 13):

#### TL;DR

The [accepted, most voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4578605/2749397) [1] by [Mark Byers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61974/mark-byers)

> ```
> def partition(pred, iterable):
>     trues = []
>     falses = []
>     for item in iterable:
>         if pred(item):
>             trues.append(item)
>         else:
>             falses.append(item)
>     return trues, falses
> ```

is the simplest and the
fastest.

#### Benchmarking the different approaches

The different approaches that had been suggested can be classified
broadly in three categories,

1. straightforward list manipulation via `lis.append`, returning a 2-tuple
   of lists,
2. `lis.append` mediated by a functional approach, returning a 2-tuple
   of lists,
3. using the canonical recipe given in the `itertools` fine
   documentation, returning a 2-tuple of, loosely speaking, generators.

Here follows a vanilla implementation of the three techniques, first
the functional approach, then `itertools` and eventually two different
implementations of direct list manipulation, the alternative being
using the `False` is zero, `True` is one trick.

Note that this is Python3 — hence `reduce` comes from `functools` —
and that OP request a tuple like `(positives, negatives)` but my
implementations all return `(negatives, positives)`…

```
$ ipython
Python 3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul 20 2017, 13:51:32) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import functools
   ...: 
   ...: def partition_fu(p, l, r=functools.reduce):
   ...:     return r(lambda x, y: x[p(y)].append(y) or x, l, ([], []))
   ...: 

In [2]: import itertools
   ...: 
   ...: def partition_it(pred, iterable,
   ...:               filterfalse=itertools.filterfalse,
   ...:               tee=itertools.tee):
   ...:     t1, t2 = tee(iterable)
   ...:     return filterfalse(pred, t1), filter(pred, t2)
   ...: 

In [3]: def partition_li(p, l):
   ...:     a, b = [], []
   ...:     for n in l:
   ...:         if p(n):
   ...:             b.append(n)
   ...:         else:
   ...:             a.append(n)
   ...:     return a, b
   ...: 

In [4]: def partition_li_alt(p, l):
   ...:     x = [], []
   ...:     for n in l: x[p(n)].append(n)
   ...:     return x
   ...:
```

We need a predicate to apply to our lists and lists (again, loosely
speaking) on which to operate.

```
In [5]: p = lambda n:n%2

In [6]: five, ten = range(50000), range(100000)
```

To overcome the problem in testing the `itertools` approach, that was
reported by [joeln](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1017546/joeln) on
Oct 31 '13 at 6:17

> Nonsense. You've calculated the time taken to construct the
>   generators in `filterfalse` and `filter`, but you've not iterated
>   through the input or called `pred` once! The advantage of the
>   `itertools` recipe is that it does not materialise any list, or look
>   further ahead in the input than necessary. It calls `pred` twice as
>   often and takes almost twice as long as Byers et al.

I have thought of a void loop that just instantiates all the couples
of elements in the two iterables returned by the different partition
functions.

First we use two fixed lists to have an idea of the
overload implied (using the very convenient IPython's magic `%timeit`)

```
In [7]: %timeit for e, o in zip(five, five): pass
4.21 ms ± 39.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Next we use the different implementations, one after the other

```
In [8]: %timeit for e, o in zip(*partition_fu(p, ten)): pass
53.9 ms ± 112 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [9]: %timeit for e, o in zip(*partition_it(p, ten)): pass
44.5 ms ± 3.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit for e, o in zip(*partition_li(p, ten)): pass
36.3 ms ± 101 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [11]: %timeit for e, o in zip(*partition_li_alt(p, ten)): pass
37.3 ms ± 109 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [12]:
```

#### Comments

The plainest of the approaches is also the fastest one.

Using the `x[p(n)]` trick is, ehm, useless because at every step you
have to index a data structure, giving you a *slight* penalty — it's
however nice to know if you want to persuade a survivor of a declining
culture at pythonizing.

The functional approach, that is *operatively* equivalent to the
alternative `append` implementation, is ~50% slower, possibly due to
the fact that we have an extra (w/r to predicate evaluation) function
call for each list element.

The `itertools` approach has the (customary) advantages that ❶ no
potentially large list is instantiated and ❷ the input list is not
entirely processed if you break out of the consumer loop, but when we
use it it is slower because of the need to apply the predicate on both
ends of the `tee`

#### Aside

I've fallen in love with the `object.mutate() or object` idiom that
was exposed by [Marii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/474772/marii)
in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4579086/2749397) showing
a functional approach to the problem — I'm afraid that, sooner or later,
I'm going to abuse it.

#### Footnotes

[1] Accepted and most voted as today, Sep 14 2017 — but of course I have the highest hopes for this answer of mine!

Answer (score 7):

I think groupby might be more relevant here:

http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

For example, splitting a list into odd and even numbers (or could be an arbitrary number of groups):

```
>>> l=range(6)
>>> key=lambda x: x % 2 == 0
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> {k:list(g) for k,g in groupby(sorted(l,key=key),key=key)}
    {False: [1, 3, 5], True: [0, 2, 4]}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this calls key twice. If key is a potentially expensive operation (e.g. tests to see if a remote URL is accessible), this solution won't do.

Answer (score 7):

You can look at [`django.utils.functional.partition`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/functional.py#L379-L390) solution:

```
def partition(predicate, values):
    """
    Splits the values into two sets, based on the return value of the function
    (True/False). e.g.:

        >>> partition(lambda x: x > 3, range(5))
        [0, 1, 2, 3], [4]
    """
    results = ([], [])
    for item in values:
        results[predicate(item)].append(item)
    return results
```

In my opinion it's *the most elegant* solution presented here.

This part is not documented, only source code can be found on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/utils/functional/

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have duplicate element in your list you can definitely use set:

```
>>> a = [1,4,12,7,42]
>>> b = filter(lambda x: x > 10, [1,4,12,7,42])
>>> no_b = set(a) - set(b)
set([1, 4, 7])
```

or you can do by a list comprehensible:

```
>>> no_b = [i for i in a if i not in b]
```

N.B: it's not a function but just knowing the first fitler() result you can deduce the element that didn't much your filter criterion .

Comment: Sets don't maintain ordering. The list comprehension is no different to a second `filter()`, which OP explicitly stated he doesn't like.

Comment: Note that the list comprehension version is `O(n*m)`, which is no good with a more than a few dozen elements. `b_set = set(b)` and `... if i not in b` in the list comprehension improves this though.

Answer (score 3):

I just had exactly this requirement. I'm not keen on the itertools recipe since it involves two separate passes through the data. Here's my implementation:

```
def filter_twoway(test, data):
    "Like filter(), but returns the passes AND the fails as two separate lists"
    collected = {True: [], False: []}
    for datum in data:
        collected[test(datum)].append(datum)
    return (collected[True], collected[False])
```

Comment: The itertools recipe has the benefit of creating generators rather than lists.

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse

def filter2(predicate, iterable):
    return filter(predicate, iterable), list(ifilterfalse(predicate, iterable))
```

Comment: Doesn't this count as "call filter twice"? If `iterable` is a single-pass iterable this doesn't work

Comment: This is actually very similar to the implementation in itertools recipes.

Comment: @Mark: except that the recipe uses `tee()`, which duplicates the iterable so that it works also with single-pass iterables

Comment: @Giuseppe: hmm, good point. As someone else has already suggested the `partition()` function in the itertools recipes (which I didn't know about), I'll just leave it as is and upvote that other solution.

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers either partition an iterable into two *lists*, or inefficiently partition it into two generators. Here is an implementation that efficiently partitions an iterable into two *generators*, i.e. the predicate function is called at most once for each element in the iterable. One instance where you might want to use this version is if your need to partition a very large (or even infinite) iterable with an expensive to compute predicate.

```py
from collections import deque

def partition(pred, iterable):
    seq = iter(iterable)
    true_buffer = deque()
    false_buffer = deque()
    def true_iter():
        while True:
            while true_buffer:
                yield true_buffer.popleft()
            item = next(seq)
            if pred(item):
                yield item
            else:
                false_buffer.append(item)
    def false_iter():
        while True:
            while false_buffer:
                yield false_buffer.popleft()
            item = next(seq)
            if not pred(item):
                yield item
            else:
                true_buffer.append(item)
    return true_iter(), false_iter()
```

Basically, this steps through each item in the the iterator, checks the predicate, and either yields it, if the corresponding generator is being used, or puts it in the buffer for the other iterable. Additionally, each generator will first pull items from its buffer before checking the original iterable. Note that each partition has it's own buffer which grows each time the other partition is iterated, so this implementation may not be suitable for use cases where one partition is iterated much more than the other.

example use case:

```py
from itertools import count
from random import random

odds, evens = partition(lambda n: n % 2, count())
for _ in range(500):
    if random() < 0.5:
        print(next(odds))
    else:
        print(next(evens))
```

Comment: This is good, I like the attempt to make it a generator. But! The storage requirement is worst-case no better than two lists; consider a list of odds with 1 even at the end, and you iterate for next even. Since partitioning uses a boolean operation, then if the next index of evens is n, all the values between the current even iterator and n must be even. So we can do a kind of RLE and just note how many odds we skipped to get to that even. The buffer then becomes just skip counts, rather than actual lists of the contents. This also helps with the case where the items being iterated are large.

Comment: @PhilH For some iterators like range, storing skip counts would be more efficient. But in the general case, teeing an iterator will need to use a buffer anyway, since the iterator values can't be easily reproduced. I'm going to keep the answer more general, but be more explicit about the memory tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone seems to think that their solution is the best, so I decided to use timeit to test all of them.  I used "def is_odd(x): return x & 1" as my predicate function, and "xrange(1000)" as the iterable.  Here is my version of Python:

```
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
```

And here are the results of my testing:

```
Mark Byers
1000 loops, best of 3: 325 usec per loop

cldy
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.96 msec per loop

Dan S
1000 loops, best of 3: 412 usec per loop

TTimo
1000 loops, best of 3: 503 usec per loop
```

Those are all comparable to each other.  Now, let's try using the example given in the Python documentation.

```
import itertools

def partition(pred, iterable,
              # Optimized by replacing global lookups with local variables
              # defined as default values.
              filter=itertools.ifilter,
              filterfalse=itertools.ifilterfalse,
              tee=itertools.tee):
    'Use a predicate to partition entries into false entries and true entries'
    # partition(is_odd, range(10)) --> 0 2 4 6 8   and  1 3 5 7 9
    t1, t2 = tee(iterable)
    return filterfalse(pred, t1), filter(pred, t2)
```

This seems to be a bit faster.

```
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.58 usec per loop
```

The itertools example code beats all comers by a factor of at least 100!  The moral is, don't keep re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Nonsense. You've calculated the time taken to construct the generators in `filterfalse` and `filter`, but you've not iterated through the input or called `pred` once! The advantage of the `itertools` recipe is that it does not materialise any list, or look further ahead in the input than necessary. It calls `pred` twice as often and takes almost twice as long as Byers et al.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of good answers already. I like to use this:

```
def partition( pred, iterable ):
    def _dispatch( ret, v ):
        if ( pred( v ) ):
            ret[0].append( v )
        else:
            ret[1].append( v )
        return ret
    return reduce( _dispatch, iterable, ( [], [] ) )

if ( __name__ == '__main__' ):
    import random
    seq = range( 20 )
    random.shuffle( seq )
    print( seq )
    print( partition( lambda v : v > 10, seq ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Concise code for appending to target list

```
    def partition(cond,inputList):
        a,b= [],[]
        for item in inputList:
            target = a if cond(item) else b
            target.append(item)
        return a, b


    >>> a, b= partition(lambda x: x > 10,[1,4,12,7,42])
    >>> a
    [12, 42]
    >>> b
    [1, 4, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

The three top voted answers to [an equivalent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949098/python-split-a-list-based-on-a-condition) propose to use `itertools.tee()` (as already covered here) and two even simpler approaches as wells.

Answer (score 0):

The `collections.defaultdict` method is an excellent helper for sorting operations.

```
import collections

input_list = ['a','b','ana','beta','gamma']
filter_key = lambda x: len(x) == 1    

## sorting code
cc = collections.defaultdict(list)
for item in input_list: cc[ filter_key(item) ].append( item )

print(cc)
```

This approach will also work for any number of categories generated by the `filter_key` function.