# List splitting by predicate

Tags: python

Is there a more concise way to split a list into two lists by a predicate?

```
errors, okays = [], []
for r in results:
    if success_condition(r):
        okays.append(r)
    else:
        errors.append(r)
```

I understand that this can be turned into an ugly one-liner using `reduce`; this is not what I'm looking for.

*Update:* calculating `success_condition` only once per element is desirable.

Comment: Your code is fine. All proposed solutions are looping and appling the filtering function twice.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti: I agree with your first sentence, but your second is wrong-- see dbaupp's.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti, and dfb's second suggestion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python equivalent of filter() getting two output lists (i.e. partition of a list)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578590/python-equivalent-of-filter-getting-two-output-lists-i-e-partition-of-a-list)

Comment: I also agree with @PaoloMoretti's first statement, this is code is fine.  There's no advantage of these solutions over yours

Comment: Many of the alternatives here involve calling `success_condition` twice for each result. This can be a bad idea if it is expensive to execute or has side effects

Comment: @gnibbler, that was already discussed about 3 comments up.

Comment: @dbaupp, just making it clear _why_ it's potentially bad to call it twice

Comment: "I understand that this can be turned into an ugly one-liner using `reduce`" – BTW: this is a tautology: `reduce` is a general method of iteration, *everything* that can be expressed with iteration (thus also everything that can be expressed with `map`, `filter` or comprehensions) can be expressed with `reduce`, see [the Wikipedia page for `fold`](http://Wikipedia.Org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Universality) for a proof.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I do know that `list` and `fold()` are different ways to say the same thing, and any catamorphism can be expressed using fold. What I'm interested in is a more compact but readable way to express the 6-liner in Python, maybe using some built-in / standard function I failed to think about.

Comment: Usually, that operation is called `partition` for the special case of partitioning a collection into two collections based on a boolean predicate and `group_by` for the more general case of grouping by an arbitrary key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: split a list based on a condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949098/python-split-a-list-based-on-a-condition)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe

```
for r in results:
    (okays if success_condition(r) else errors).append(r)
```

But that doesn't look/feel very Pythonic.

---

Not directly relevant, but if one is looking for efficiency, caching the method look-ups would be better:

```
okays_append = okays.append
errors_append = errors.append

for r in results:
    (okays_append if success_condition(r) else errors_append)(r)
```

Which is even less Pythonic.

Answer (score 5):

```
errors, okays = [], []
for r in results:
    (errors, okays)[success_condition(r)].append(r)
```

Comment: Damn cool :) I wonder if it passes our code review, but anyway.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
errors = [ r for r in results if not success_condition(r)]
okays = [ r for r in results if success_condition(r)]
```

Or

```
bools = [ success_condition(r) for r in results ]
```

and then replace above (via `zip` or `enumerate`) if success_condition is a costly call..

Comment: But in order to get the good ones, you need to filter again -- effectively checking each element twice (which is potentially expensive).

Comment: Yes, this is true, but he asked for concision, not efficiency

Comment: @dfb I deleted it because it wasn't actually more succinct.

Comment: I think by the time you combine `bools` with `zip` it's not going to be very concise anymore

Comment: @gnibbler - really? it turns into `okays = [ r[0] for r in zip(results,bools) if r[1]]`. Not too much worse... or were you referring to the fact that it's 3 lines instead of 2?

Comment: @dfb, comparing the 3 lines to the 6 from the OP, in my head it looks like you're building a list of bools and not really gaining anything

Answer (score 3):

I find the following construction to be elegant and readable:

```py
successes = [r for r in results if success_condition(r)]
failures = [r for r in results if r not in successes]
```

And it only calls the `success_condition` function once per element instead of twice.

Yeah, it's O(n²) when using lists, but there is little perceptible performance penalty for lists with fewer than a million elements.

If order doesn't matter, you could use sets with `{}` instead of `[]`:

```py
okays = {r for r in results if success_condition(r)}
errors = set(results) - okays
```

Or rely on the fact that dicts retain insertion order in Python 3.7+:

```py
okays = {r: None for r in results if success_condition(r)}
errors = [r for r in results if r not in okays]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the `filter` function?

```
okays = filter(success_condition, results)
errors = filter(lambda (x): not success_condition(x), results)
```

Comment: It applies the predicate twice which is not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a generator expression or list comprehension  with side-effect.(just to make it look concise):

```
>>> errors, okays = [], []
>>> [okays.append(r) if success_condition(r) else errors.append(r)  for r in results]
```

with generator expression:

```
>>> errors, okays = [], []
>>> list(okays.append(r) if success_condition(r) else errors.append(r)  for r in results)
```

Comment: This doesn't really work. Nothing in the generator expression is executed yet. You need to use a list comprehension (or iterate through the generator expression somehow, e.g. `[None for _ in <genexpr> if False]`).

Comment: @dbaupp I guess just `list(<gen expr>)` will do fine.

Comment: Of course (that is equivalent to a list comprehension). But my other proposal avoids allocating a large block of memory for the list which is then immediately discarded.

Comment: (Although doing some quick testing just now indicates that my trickery is slower than the plain `list(..)` call, haha!)

Comment: `any(<get expr>)` is better as `list.append` always returns `False` it will run through the whole thing