# partitioning arrays in python based on a predicate

Tags: python, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python equivalent of filter() getting two output lists (i.e. partition of a list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578590/python-equivalent-of-filter-getting-two-output-lists-i-e-partition-of-a-list)

I have an array in python and want to split it into two arrays, one where elements match a predicate and the other where elements do not.

Is there an simpler way (or more Pythonic) than the following:

```
>>> def partition(a, pred):
...   ain = []
...   aout = []
...   for x in a:
...     if pred(x):
...       ain.append(x)
...     else:
...       aout.append(x)
...   return (ain, aout)
...
>>> partition(range(1,10), lambda x: x%3 == 1)
([1, 4, 7], [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9])
```

Comment: huh, I tried searching before posting & couldn't find it -- thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What you currently have is simpler and more efficient than any other way to do this.

Here are a few potential options on how you could rewrite it this code, and why I think your version is better:

- Using sets - **order isn't preserved, only works on hashable contents**
- Using tee/filter/ifilterfalse - **depending on how you use the result, you end up using more memory, and iterating twice**
- Using numpy - **not applicable to generic iterables, need to iterate twice to get results for both conditions**

Answer (score 2):

From http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

> ```
> def partition(pred, iterable):
>     'Use a predicate to partition entries into false entries and true entries'
>     # partition(is_odd, range(10)) --> 0 2 4 6 8   and  1 3 5 7 9
>     t1, t2 = tee(iterable)
>     return ifilterfalse(pred, t1), filter(pred, t2)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
def partition(a,pred):
  f1 = set(filter(pred,a))
  f2 = set(a) - f1
  return f1,f2
```

more pythonic ... but not sure if its faster

[edit] and i dont think order is preserved ... (and there are better answers in both comments with links)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to NumPy? The indexing capacities of Numpy makes it quite easy to select entries of a numpy `ndarray` depending on some condition. For example

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(1, 10)
>>> condition = (a % 3 == 1)
>>> a[condition]
array([1, 4, 7])
>>> a[~condition]
array([2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9])
```

NumPy is especially efficient with large arrays. For small ones, not that much.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way of saying the same thing. Note that the order of the two lists is reversed.

```
def partition(a, pred):
    aout_ain = [], []
    for x in a:
        aout_ain[pred(x)].append(x)
    return aout_ain
```

If you need the "ins" to be first then simply add a `not`

```
def partition(a, pred):
    ain_aout = [], []
    for x in a:
        ain_aout[not pred(x)].append(x)
    return ain_aout
```

Answer (score -1):

Not so `Pythonic`, but a little functional:

```
>>> partition = lambda xs, p: reduce(lambda (a, b), c: p(c) and (a + [c], b) or (a, b + [c]), xs, ([], []))
>>> print partition(range(1, 10), lambda x: x % 3 == 1)
([1, 4, 7], [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9])
```