# Python analogue for Ruby Enumerable .partition method

Tags: python, ruby, standard-library

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python equivalent of filter() getting two output lists (i.e. partition of a list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578590/python-equivalent-of-filter-getting-two-output-lists-i-e-partition-of-a-list)

Is there any built-in function or maybe some module in python standard library, that simulates  `Enumerable.partition` behaviour from Ruby and iterates over an object just once to get two lists/tuples based on a predicate function passed?

Comment: it's here: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes. And this has been asked a number of times. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578590/python-equivalent-of-filter-getting-two-output-lists-i-e-partition-of-a-list

Answer (score 1):

Stolen shamelessly from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949098/python-split-a-list-based-on-a-condition) - you can use the `tee` function from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import tee

def split_on_condition(seq, condition):
    l1,l2 = tee((condition(item),item) for item in seq)
    return (i for p, i in l1 if p), (i for p, i in l2 if not p)
```

Comment: no need to copy and paste, we can close the question for being an exact duplicate