# How does java's iterator.remove() translate to python?

Tags: java, python, concurrency, iterator

I have a python set that I need to iterate over, and for each element, check if it satisfies a constraint, and if so, remove it and add it to a different, possibly already nonempty set. I could just add it to a buffer and then, after the loop is complete, iterate through the buffer and remove its contents from the set, but there must be a better way to do this.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
for elem in S:
  if (P(elem)):
    S.remove(elem)
    T.add(elem)
```

This doesn't work.

Here's the fix that would work but is unclean:

```
B = set()
for elem in S:
  if (P(elem)):
    B.add(elem)
    T.add(elem)
for elem in B:
  S.remove(elem)
```

EDIT:
The best solution seems to be:

```
for elem in S.copy():
  if (P(elem)):
    S.remove(elem)
    T.add(elem)
```

Comment: From context, I surmise you are dealing with a *list*, not just any iterable (which are usually not directly addressable or mutable).

Comment: The function for this is called "partition"; however, I know of no such standard Python construct although it is fairly easy to create. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578590/python-equivalent-of-filter-getting-two-output-lists-i-e-partition-of-a-list (some of these allow lazy iterators; others force evaluation)

Answer (score 2):

For a list, create a copy before iterating:

```
for elem in S[:]:
```

where the `[:]` slice notation creates a copy of the full list. You cannot otherwise remove elements from a list while iterating over it.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a list comprehension to create `T` and then remove all elements in `T` from `S`.

```
T = set([elem for elem in S if P(elem)])
S = S - T
```

Comment: This only works if T is empty to begin with. The thing that made my problem nontrivial to me was that T may be nonempty.

Comment: @user1123936: One option is to use a temporary set `X` and then add `X` to `T` after the code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If iterating over the list twice and calling `P()` twice for each item is not an issue this would be the most readable solution::

```
T = [x for x in S if P(elem)]
S = [x for x in S if not P(elem)]
```