# Is it possible to compile results into unique lists from inside of a comprehension?

Tags: python

The context is splitting a list of integers into their own even and odd lists.

```
    even = []
    odd = []
    for i in my_list:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            even.append(i)
        else:
            odd.append(i)
```

Is there a way to turn the above into a nice, compact list comprehension..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not without using side effects and throwing away the result. You can do this though:

```
even = []
odd = []
for i in my_list:
    (odd if i % 2 else even).append(i)
```

This problem in general is called *partitioning* the list, you can find [some solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578590/python-equivalent-of-filter-getting-two-output-lists-i-e-partition-of-a-list) by searching SO, but none are much cleaner (in Python).

Comment: For the case of `i%2` it turns out this is slower (on my computer) than doing 2 list comprehensions (and calculating i%2 twice as many times). Obviously this changes for a more expensive partition function. Extracting the `append` methods is still a little faster though.

Comment: If you're really trying to optimize, what about `a = [odd.append, even.append]; for i in my_list: a[i%2](i)`?

Comment: I wasn't trying to optimize, I was removing redundant code. But is indexing faster than the ternary if? How about `oa, ea = odd.append, even.append; for i in my_list: (oa if i % 2 else ea)(i)`?

Comment: What is really helpful for speed is removing the `append` calls. That's why two list comprehensions are so fast.

Answer (score 4):

Not really, you can hack something up using sideeffects, but this is not what list comprehensions are for

```
>>> even = []
>>> odd = []
>>> [(odd if i%2 else even).append(i) for i in range(10)]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None] # it's a waste to make this list
>>> even
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
>>> odd
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Slightly less wasteful (but harder to understand) is this

```
>>> even = []
>>> odd = [i for i in range(10) if i%2 or even.append(i)]
>>> even
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
>>> odd
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

You can however use the conditional from the first list comprehension to simplify your loop

```
even = []
odd = []
for i in my_list:                     # Doesn't make a pointless list of `None`
    (odd if i%2 else even).append(i)
```

If `my_list` is really  long, it may be worth binding the append methods to local variables to save the extra lookups (saves ~30% for list of 10000)

```
even = []
odd = []
even_append = even.append
odd_append = odd.append
for i in my_list:
    (odd_append if i%2 else even_append)(i)
```

Another speedup is to use `i&1` instead of `i%2` to select even or odd

Comment: It _is_ possible to hack away something without side effects, but it'll be wasteful. See my answer.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez, yes, it's very poor performance. Two list comprehensions is probably faster

Answer (score 3):

If odd/even match the list indices, you can use slicing to do this:

```
>>> my_list=list(range(20))
>>> even,odd=my_list[0::2],my_list[1::2]
>>> even
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
>>> odd
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
```

If you just want compact (and fast):

```
>>> isodd=lambda x: x%2                                                     
>>> random.shuffle(my_list)
>>> even,odd=[x for x in my_list if not isodd(x)],[x for x in my_list if isodd(x)]
>>> even
[12, 6, 2, 18, 14, 0, 10, 16, 8, 4]
>>> odd
[17, 1, 19, 11, 15, 5, 9, 13, 7, 3]
```

Comment: That'll work only if the list is sorted, it won't work for the general case when the predicate is something more complex than even/odd.

Answer (score 1):

Single pass:

```
my_list=[i for i in range(50)]
lists=[[], []]
[ lists[x % 2].append(x) for x in my_list ]
print lists[0]
print lists[1]
```

Comment: Valid point ;) However, it seemed wasteful to iterate twice over the same list just to split out odd and evens -- especially if the list is huge.

Comment: @Zack, it _is_ wasteful. This is why you should stick to a simple `for` loop for this pattern

Answer (score 1):

Not the shortest (or nicest) list comprehension in the world, but at least it's side effect-free, it's written in a functional programming style without using `append()`. Here you go:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

even, odd = [[x for x in y if x is not None] for y in zip(*((None, e) if e % 2 else (e, None) for e in lst))]

even
=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

odd
=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Conveniently you don't have `0` in `lst` :) You'll need `x is not None` to obfuscate it further :)

Comment: @gnibbler obfuscated, er, fixed! :)