# python equivalent of scala partition

Tags: python, scala

I'm currently porting some Scala code to Python and I am wondering what is the most pythonic way to do something similar to Scala's `partition`? In particular, in the Scala code I have a situation where I am partitioning a list of items based on whether they return true or false from some filter predicate that I pass in:

```
val (inGroup,outGroup) = items.partition(filter)
```

What is the best way to do something like this in Python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python equivalent of filter() getting two output lists (i.e. partition of a list)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578590/python-equivalent-of-filter-getting-two-output-lists-i-e-partition-of-a-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using filter (require two iteration):

```
>>> items = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> inGroup = filter(is_even, items) # list(filter(is_even, items)) in Python 3.x
>>> outGroup = filter(lambda n: not is_even(n), items)
>>> inGroup
[2, 4]
>>> outGroup
```

Simple loop:

```
def partition(item, filter_):
    inGroup, outGroup = [], []
    for n in items:
        if filter_(n):
            inGroup.append(n)
        else:
            outGroup.append(n)
    return inGroup, outGroup
```

Example:

```
>>> items = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> inGroup, outGroup = partition(items, is_even)
>>> inGroup
[2, 4]
>>> outGroup
[1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: To clarify something that's confusing me here: in the "simple loop" code do you mean to write `if is_even(n):` or `if filter_(n):`

Comment: @shuttle87, I meant to write `if filter_(n)`. I fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

Scala

```
val (inGroup,outGroup) = items.partition(filter)
```

Python - Using List Comprehension

```
inGroup = [e for e in items if _filter(e)]
outGroup = [e for e in items if not _filter(e)]
```

Answer (score 2):

This version is lazy and doesn't apply the predicate twice to the same element:

```
def partition(it, pred):
    buf = [[], []]
    it = iter(it)

    def get(t):
        while True:
            while buf[t]:
                yield buf[t].pop(0)
            x = next(it)
            if t == bool(pred(x)):
                yield x
            else:
                buf[not t].append(x)

    return get(True), get(False)
```

Example:

```
even = lambda x: x % 2 == 0

e, o = partition([1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2], even)
print list(e)
print list(o)
```

Comment: Try `print(list(zip(o,e)))`. It should print `[(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2)]`, but it prints `[(1,2),(1,2)]`. To fix it, put the first `while` loop inside the second `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Scala has rich list processing api, and Python is much as that.

You should read document [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html). And you may find a receipe of partition.

```py
from itertools import ifilterfalse, ifilter, islice, tee, count

def partition(pred, iterable):
    '''
    >>> is_even = lambda i: i % 2 == 0
    >>> even, no_even = partition(is_even, xrange(11))
    >>> list(even)
    [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
    >>> list(no_even)
    [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

    # Lazy evaluation
    >>> infi_list = count(0)
    >>> ingroup, outgroup = partition(is_even, infi_list)
    >>> list(islice(ingroup, 5))
    [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
    >>> list(islice(outgroup, 5))
    [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
    '''
    t1, t2 = tee(iterable)
    return ifilter(pred, t1), ifilterfalse(pred, t2)
```

Comment: Where is filterfalse located?