# if-else in python list comprehensions

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, list-comprehension

is it possible to write list comprehensions for the following python code:

```
for str in range(0,len(mixed_content)):
    if (mixed_content[str].isdigit()):
        num_list.append(mixed_content[str])
    else:
        string_list.append(mixed_content[str])
```

can we use else block in list comprehensions ? I tried to write list comprehensions for above code :

```
num_list , string_list = [   mixed_content[str]  for str in range(0,len(mixed_content)) if(mixed_content[str].isdigit()) else ]
```

Comment: Don't use `str` as variable name.

Comment: You're building two lists? `num_list` and `string_list`?

Comment: I'd especially not use `str` as the name of an integer.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578590/python-equivalent-of-filter-getting-two-output-lists-i-e-partition-of-a-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only construct one list at a time with list comprehension.  You'll want something like:

```
nums = [foo for foo in mixed_list if foo.isdigit()]
strings = [foo for foo in mixed_list if not foo.isdigit()]
```

Comment: While this solves the problem, this is one of the cases when list comprehension is at disadvantage against regular loop - because you loop twice over data, and check each value twice.

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible as-is, but if you're looking for one-liners you can do that with a ternary expression inside your loop (saves a test and is compact):

```
num_list=[]
string_list=[]
for s in ["45","hello","56","foo"]:
    (num_list if s.isdigit() else string_list).append(s)

print(num_list,string_list)
```

result:

```
['45', '56'] ['hello', 'foo']
```

Notes:

- despite the parenthesized syntax and the context of the question, `(num_list if s.isdigit() else string_list)` is not a generator, a ternary expression (protected between parentheses to counter `.append` precedence) which returns `num_list` if s is a sequence of (positive) digits and `string_list` if s otherwise.
- this code won't work with negative numbers because `isdigits` will return false. You'll have to code a special function for that (classical problem here on SO)

Comment: Much appreciated. I knew the component parts but never seen it assembled like this (in one line and with a `.append()` on the end) so it seemed a bit like magic :).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of using `x if b else y` in a list comprehension.

```
mixed_content = "y16m10"

num_list, string_list = zip(
    *[(ch, None) if ch.isdigit() else (None, ch) for ch in mixed_content])
num_list = filter(None, num_list)
string_list = filter(None, string_list)
print num_list, string_list
```

Comment: I was also going to post the *padding* with `None` and then *filter* later, but I figured I'll be running 3 iterations (or even more with the transpose) on the list length. Witty one though (+1)

Comment: I like this idea of using the `zip(*` to turn a list of tuples into the tuple of lists.  For some problems this might a good way of generating 2 lists from a single comprehension.  But here we are stuck with the extra step of filtering out the `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's initialize variables:

```
>>> mixed_content='ab42c1'; num_list=[]; string_list=[]
```

Because the OP asked about using "if-else in python list comprehensions," let's show that that can be done:

```
>>> [num_list.append(c) if c.isdigit() else string_list.append(c) for c in mixed_content]
[None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Let's verify that we have the lists that you want:

```
>>> num_list, string_list
(['4', '2', '1'], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Comment: While this does technically work, it's usually a bad idea to use a list comprehension when all you really want is a loop. Just write a `for` loop instead and you won't get a list of `None` values.

Comment: Technically, the commands in the `for` loop still return `None` values

Comment: Sure, it's building a list out of the `None`s that's wasteful.

Comment: In simple time tests, this list comprehension is only slightly slower than the OP's loop.  I'm bothered more by the use of a list comprehension for its side effects (the appends) rather than its primary output.  It violates the spirit, if not the letter, of list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want with two list comprehensions:

```
num_list = [num for num in mixed_content if num.isdigit()]
string_list = [string for string in mixed_content if not string.isdigit()]
```

The else clause is not supported in list comprehensions:

```
>>> [c for c in range(5) if c == 1 else 0]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

A super messy and unpractical way of doing is:

```
mixed_content = ['a','b','c',"4"]
string_list = []

print [y for y in [x if mixed_content[x].isdigit() else string_list.append(mixed_content[x]) for x in range(0,len(mixed_content))] if y != None]
print string_list
```

Returns:

```
[3]
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Basically list comprehension for your condition and then filter that list comprehension to only accept non `None`