# Match list string from a dataframe column and return " partial" and "full match" string in in col1 and "not matched" in col2 in master dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, regex

I have a list of strings (words) which I want to compare to another dataframe column which has free hand text.

I want list to be compared with dataframe column and return "matched and partial matched" texts in one column and remaining leftover texts in another column.

Tried Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re

skills = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\m1056565\Downloads\final_skill.xlsx")

skills.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], inplace=True, axis=1)

jd = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\m1056565\Downloads\job_descriptiopn.xlsx", nrows=100)

jd.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], inplace=True, axis=1)

skills['skills_lower'] = list(map(lambda x: str(x).lower(), skills['skills']))
repo = skills['skills_lower'].to_list()

repo = list(map(str.lower, repo))

repo = "|".join(repo)

jd['JobDescription_lower'] = list(map(lambda x: str(x).lower(), jd['JobDescription']))

jd['match'] = pd.Series(list(map(lambda x: " ".join(list(filter(lambda y: y in repo, x.split()))), jd['JobDescription_lower'])))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This code is a little messy but it should work:

```
    import pandas as pd
    from functools import reduce

    l = ['apple', 'python']

    # this is just an example dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['apple aple xyz def', 'pythn jef', 'asdf', 'skjd aple']})

    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578590/python-equivalent-of-filter-getting-two-output-lists-i-e-partition-of-a-list
    def partition(string):
        string = string.split()
        p = lambda x: any([set(x).issubset(word) for word in l])
        result = reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0]+[y], x[1]) if p(y) else (x[0], x[1]+[y]), string,  ([], []))
        return [' '.join(sl) for sl in result]

    result = df['text'].transform(lambda x: partition(x))
    result_df = pd.DataFrame(result.apply(lambda x: [x[0], x[1]]).tolist(), columns=['Match', 'Not_Match'])
    df[['Match', 'Not_Match']] = result_df
```

Here is the result:

```
    |    | text               | Match      | Not_Match   |
    |---:|:-------------------|:-----------|:------------|
    |  0 | apple aple xyz def | apple aple | xyz def     |
    |  1 | pythn jef          | pythn      | jef         |
    |  2 | asdf               |            | asdf        |
    |  3 | skjd aple          | aple       | skjd        |
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).