# How to efficiently split a pair of arrays based on a condition on one of them

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 2D numpy arrays - real `r`, which contains points in space, given by their Cartesian coordinates, and `v`, a complex vector defined at each of these points. I would like to split both of these arrays, based on some condition on `r`.

e.g., `r1` contains all points with the first cartesian coordinate is positive, and `v1` gives the corresponding values of `v`. All other points and their corresponding vectors go into .

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949098/python-split-a-list-based-on-a-condition), and the fact that `zip` is essentially it's own inverse, I currently have the following solution:

```
r1, v1 = zip(*[rv for rv in zip(r, v) if rv[0][0] > 0.0])
r2, v2 = zip(*[rv for rv in zip(r, v) if rv[0][0] <= 0.0])
r1 = np.array(r1)
r2 = np.array(r2)
v1 = np.array(v1)
v2 = np.array(v2)
```

This works well enough for my purposes, however it involves conversion to large lists of arrays, which is surely quite inefficient.

*Is there an alternative solution, which is fast, concise and avoids the creation of intermediate lists?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use bool array as index to filter out values:

create some random test data first:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
r = np.random.rand(10,2)-0.5
v = np.random.rand(10) + np.random.rand(10)*1j
```

then:

```
idx = r[:,0] > 0 # idx is a bool array 
r1 = r[idx]
v1 = v[idx]

r2 = r[~idx] # ~idx compute bit-wise NOT, element-wise
v2 = v[~idx]
```

Comment: very nice, I didn't know you could use a bool array to index stuff

Answer (score 2):

When checking conditions of numpy arrays, I usually end up with using `numpy.where`, with only a condition as arguments, it returns the indices of the array:

```
i1 = numpy.where(r[:,0]>0.0) # i1 has now the row indices where column 0 > 0.0
i2 = numpy.where(r[:,0]<=0.0)
r1 = numpy.take(r,i1[0],0)       # take slices of r along axis 0
v1 = numpy.take(v,i1[0],0)
r2 = numpy.take(r,i2[0],0)
v2 = numpy.take(v,i2[0],0)
```

Somewhat shorter, just use compress in this case, which combines both:

```
larger = r[:,0]>0.0
r1 = numpy.compress(larger,r,0)
```

I do not know if this is faster, but it only uses arrays, no intermediate lists

EDIT: you might also want to look at masked arrays if you want to operate on r, v directly

Comment: That's a nice answer, I didn't know about the single argument form of "where". But the bool array indexing is even better!