# Simple way to group items into buckets

Tags: python

I often want to bucket an unordered collection in python. [`itertools.groubpy`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) does the right sort of thing but almost always requires massaging to sort the items first and catch the iterators before they're consumed.

Is there any quick way to get this behavior, either through a standard python module or a simple python idiom?

```
>>> bucket('thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog', lambda x: x in 'aeiou')
{False: ['t', 'h', 'q', 'c', 'k', 'b', 'r', 'w', 'n', 'f', 'x', 'j', 'm', 'p',
    's', 'v', 'r', 't', 'h', 'l', 'z', 'y', 'd', 'g'],
 True: ['e', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'o', 'e', 'e', 'a', 'o']}
>>> bucket(xrange(21), lambda x: x % 10)
{0: [0, 10, 20],
 1: [1, 11],
 2: [2, 12],
 3: [3, 13],
 4: [4, 14],
 5: [5, 15],
 6: [6, 16],
 7: [7, 17],
 8: [8, 18],
 9: [9, 19]}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This has come up several times before -- [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793772/how-to-split-a-sequence-according-to-a-predicate), [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949098/python-split-a-list-based-on-a-condition), [(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578590/python-equivalent-of-filter-getting-two-output-lists-i-e-partition-of-a-list) -- and there's a partition recipe in the [`itertools` recipes](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), but to my knowledge there's nothing in the standard library.. although I was surprised a few weeks ago by `accumulate`, so who knows what's lurking there these days? :^)

When I need this behaviour, I use

```
from collections import defaultdict

def partition(seq, key):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for x in seq:
        d[key(x)].append(x)
    return d
```

and get on with my day.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple two liner

```
d = {}
for x in "thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog": d.setdefault(x in 'aeiou', []).append(x)
```

**Edit:**

Just adding your other case for completeness.

```
d={}
for x in xrange(21): d.setdefault(x%10, []).append(x)
```

Comment: I always find `defaultdict` to be nicer than d.setdefault.etc type tricks

Comment: @wim: Yeah, I always forget that it exists. That is why I up-voted DSM's answer.

Comment: wim: actually, I like `setdefault` better than `defaultdict`. It's pretty much the same amount of code either way, but `setdefault` is explicit about it, you can use it on existing dicts as you find you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variant of `partition()` from above when the predicate is boolean, avoiding the cost of a `dict`/`defaultdict`:

```
def boolpartition(seq, pred):
    passing, failing = [], []
    for item in seq:
        (passing if pred(item) else failing).append(item)
    return passing, failing
```

Example usage:

```
>>> even, odd = boolpartition([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], lambda x: x % 2 == 0)
>>> even
[2, 4]
>>> odd
[1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

If its a `pandas.DataFrame` the following also works, utilizing [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html)

```
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
df_data = pd.DataFrame(iris.data[:,0])  # we'll just take the first feature

# bucketize
n_bins = 5
feature_name = iris.feature_names[0].replace(" ", "_")
my_labels = [str(feature_name) + "_" + str(num) for num in range(0,n_bins)]
pd.cut(df_data[0], bins=n_bins, labels=my_labels)
```

yielding

```
0      0_1
1      0_0
2      0_0
[...]
```

In case you don't set the `labels`, the output is going to like this

```
0       (5.02, 5.74]
1      (4.296, 5.02]
2      (4.296, 5.02]
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use generator like this
"yield" means, that function returns on every go through

array.pop cut last element from array

```
def get_bucket(arr, n):
    while len(arr) > 0:
        l = len(arr)
        bucket = []
        for i in range(n if n < l else l):
            bucket.append(arr.pop())
        yield bucket


for b in get_bucket(list(range(123)), 5):
    print(b)

[122, 121, 120, 119, 118]
[117, 116, 115, 114, 113]
[112, 111, 110, 109, 108]
[107, 106, 105, 104, 103]
[102, 101, 100, 99, 98]
[97, 96, 95, 94, 93]
[92, 91, 90, 89, 88]
[87, 86, 85, 84, 83]
[82, 81, 80, 79, 78]
[77, 76, 75, 74, 73]
[72, 71, 70, 69, 68]
[67, 66, 65, 64, 63]
[62, 61, 60, 59, 58]
[57, 56, 55, 54, 53]
[52, 51, 50, 49, 48]
[47, 46, 45, 44, 43]
[42, 41, 40, 39, 38]
[37, 36, 35, 34, 33]
[32, 31, 30, 29, 28]
[27, 26, 25, 24, 23]
[22, 21, 20, 19, 18]
[17, 16, 15, 14, 13]
[12, 11, 10, 9, 8]
[7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
[2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit:

Using DSM's answer as a start, here is a slightly more concise, general answer:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
map(lambda x: d[x in 'aeiou'].append(x),'thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog')
```

or

```
d = defaultdict(list)
map(lambda x: d[x %10].append(x),xrange(21))
```

#

Here is a two liner:

```
d = {False:[],True:[]}
filter(lambda x: d[True].append(x) if x in 'aeiou' else d[False].append(x),"thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogs")
```

Which can of course be made a one-liner:

```
d = {False:[],True:[]};filter(lambda x: d[True].append(x) if x in 'aeiou' else d[False].append(x),"thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogs")
```

Comment: -1 The keys aren't always False and True, they should be the outputs of the callable

Comment: I'd recommend the `for x in 'thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog': d[x in 'aeiou'].append(x)` form (as in grieve's answer). I'm not really a fan of using `map` for side effects and throwing away the value.

Comment: The problem with grieves answer, though it works well, is that it costs a bit more computationally. (it calls setdefault for every element, repeated or not.) I like DSMs answer, but I wanted to see if I could get a one liner (or close to it.)

Comment: it's not really a one-liner if you're just joining two lines together with `;` !

Comment: I wasn't saying to not use `defaultdict`, I meant that changing a for loop to `map` doesn't make it more concise, it just makes it more confusing.

Comment: @wim, yes true. It does do all of the computing in one line. Mu Mind, that really depends on your perspective. Using map is a more functional style. Eh. To each his own.