# How to split a list into subsets based on a pattern?

Tags: python

I'm doing this but it feels this can be achieved with much less code. It is Python after all. Starting with a list, I split that list into subsets based on a string prefix.

```
# Splitting a list into subsets
# expected outcome:
# [['sub_0_a', 'sub_0_b'], ['sub_1_a', 'sub_1_b']]

mylist = ['sub_0_a', 'sub_0_b', 'sub_1_a', 'sub_1_b']

def func(l, newlist=[], index=0):
    newlist.append([i for i in l if i.startswith('sub_%s' % index)])
    # create a new list without the items in newlist
    l = [i for i in l if i not in newlist[index]]

    if len(l):
        index += 1
        func(l, newlist, index)

func(mylist)
```

Comment: Related: [Python: split a list based on a condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/949098/12892)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> mylist = ['sub_0_a', 'sub_0_b', 'sub_1_a', 'sub_1_b']
>>> for k,v in itertools.groupby(mylist,key=lambda x:x[:5]):
...     print k, list(v)
... 
sub_0 ['sub_0_a', 'sub_0_b']
sub_1 ['sub_1_a', 'sub_1_b']
```

or exactly as you specified it:

```
>>> [list(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(mylist,key=lambda x:x[:5])]
[['sub_0_a', 'sub_0_b'], ['sub_1_a', 'sub_1_b']]
```

Of course, the common caveats apply (Make sure your list is sorted with the same key you're using to group), and you might need a slightly more complicated key function for real world data...

Comment: `lambda x:x.split('_')[1]` would be better, considering the items might be like `sub_15_b`.

Comment: lol, that's really entertaining after the comment got deleted. :)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- Sure I could use a more complicated key function (hence my comment about real world data) -- my goal here was to demonstrate how to use `groupby` in a nice succinct way.  Once you start having `for k,v in itertools.groupby(mylist,key=lambda x: x.split('-')[1]):...` it really starts to get confusing what portion of the expression is doing what.  I opted to keep it simple so hopefully it will be more understandable and OP can modify as needed. :)

Comment: Yeah! I totally agree with the simplicity part.

Comment: And understandable it is. Good take on using itertools.groupby. Making note to self not to forget about it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [28]: mylist = ['sub_0_a', 'sub_0_b', 'sub_1_a', 'sub_1_b']

In [29]: lis=[]

In [30]: for x in mylist:
    i=x.split("_")[1]
    try:
        lis[int(i)].append(x)
    except:    
        lis.append([])
        lis[-1].append(x)
   ....:         

In [31]: lis
Out[31]: [['sub_0_a', 'sub_0_b'], ['sub_1_a', 'sub_1_b']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools`' [`groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
def get_field_sub(x): return x.split('_')[1]

mylist = sorted(mylist, key=get_field_sub)
[ (x, list(y)) for x, y in groupby(mylist, get_field_sub)]
```

Comment: Good with the sorting added to the example. +1 for the link to ``groupby`` docs :)