# How to split a list on a condition?

Tags: python

By now I didn't find a convenient way to split a list by certain conditions, for example, I have a record list:

```
 a = ((0,1),(1,0),(0,2),(1,0),(3,0),(4,0),(0,3),(1,5)....)
```

I want to split the content into 2 lists

```
alist = []
blist = []
for x in a:
    if x[0] == 0:
        alist.append(x)
    elif x[0] == 1:
        blist.append(x)
```

Not very concise.

Written as list comprehensions:

```
aList = [x for x in a if x[0] == 0]
bList = [x for x in a if x[0] == 1]
```

List comprehensions are usually good for reading and performance, but in this case the list must be iterated twice.

Is there a better way to do this job?

Comment: I think you should be comparing two ints with is.  if 1 is 1

Comment: @Jake I wouldn't recommend that. Interning small ints is an implementation detail, I think. `==` is more reliable.

Comment: @LevLevitsky Oh.  well, I learn something new every day.  Should I delete the above comment?

Comment: In that case, I will leave it in order for the conversation to be complete.  And I will now use SO to discover when to use is vs ==.

Comment: @Jake: `is` compares if two variables point to the same object. You almost always want to use `==`.

Comment: @Blender previously I believed that it compared type and value.  Similar to PHP ===. Thanks for helping clear that up.

Answer (score 6):

Well, the conditions are different, no wonder you need two loops. But if you want to sacrifice some readability,

```
aList, bList = [[x for x in a if x[0] == i] for i in (0, 1)]
```

Comment: but in this way,you actually iter it twice ,right? first for 0,and second for 1.

Comment: @Max Yes. If you want to avoid this, you have to be sure the list is already in the correct order. If this is the case, you can make use of [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Edit: no, turns out it's not necessary, see Ignacio's answer.

Comment: @InbarRose Oh come on :) It's still two loops where one would be enough. Better compliment the other answers :)

Answer (score 6):

Adding one line will make the loop more concise at the cost of readability (and FPness).

```
alist = []
blist = []
bothlists = [alist, blist]
for x in a:
  bothlists[x[0]].append(x)
```

Comment: good for simple condition check! use bothlists = ([],[]) alist,blist = bothlist,can save one line.

Comment: @Max: Actually `bothlists = alist, blist = [], []` would save two lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to make things complicated, you can import some functions from `itertools` to obfuscate your readable solution even more:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in itertools.groupby(a, itemgetter(0)):
    d[key].append(list(value))
```

Here is the output:

```
>>> print d[0]
[[(0, 1)], [(0, 2)], [(0, 3)]]
>>> print d[1]
[[(1, 0)], [(1, 0)], [(1, 5)]]
>>> print d[4]
[[(4, 0)]]
```

This code just groups the items into a dictionary using the value in the first tuple as the key. It's a little more generic than your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `filter`, see: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter

```
>>> a = ((0,1), (1,0), (0,2), (1,0), (3,0), (4,0), (0,3), (1,5))
>>> filter(lambda x: x[0] == 1, a)
((1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 5))
```

To avoid redundant code you could collect the conditions in an iterable, like so:

```
>>> fs = (lambda x: x[0] == 0, lambda x: x[0] == 1)
>>> for f in fs:
...     filter(f, a)
...
((0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3))
((1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 5))
```

Comment: This iterates through the list multiple times, so isn't an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

A dict can be more concise.

```
alist, blist = [], []
for x in a:
    {0: alist, 1: blist}.get(x[0]).append(x)
```

This is a flexible pattern that you can expand to cover other situations.

For example, you can add more choices. You can also gracefully deal with unexpected values by changing `.get(x[0])` to `.get(x[0], [])`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this that takes advantage of the speed of a list comprehension to make one list, while incrementally appending the rejects onto another list.

```py
blist = []
alist = [x for x in data if x[0]==0 or blist.append(x)]
```

This takes advantage of Python's greedily evaluating the `or`, so for any `x` that passes the `alist` criterion (`x[0]==0`) Python won't bother evaluating the second disjunct (`blist.append(x)`). This is a case where it's fairly intuitive to read Python's "or" as meaning "or else do this second thing and use its output instead" (which is technically what it always means).

This also takes advantage of the fact that `list.append` always returns a false-like `None` value, so that in the case where some `x` fails the `alist` criterion and thus gets appended to `blist` instead, the `or` still evaluates as false, so that rejected `x` still will not be included in the `alist` comprehension.

Here are `timeit` results (on my reasonably powerful desktop), each dividing a list of a million random numbers ranging 0-1 into a `small` list of those less than 0.1 and a `large` list of those larger, each trial repeated 10 times.

```
0.80 seconds: Using append to create both (suggested by @Ignacio)
0.68 seconds: Separate list comprehensions (suggested by @Max)
0.68 seconds: Using append to create large, comprehend to create small (inverse of what I would suggest!)
0.52 seconds: Using append to create small, comprehend to create large (suggested by me)
```

These results confirm what you would probably expect: primarily, list comprehension builds big lists a lot faster than `append` does, and, secondarily, 1 traversal is faster than 2.  If you can predict which list will be longer, better to build that large list by comprehension, while appending just a few rejects into the smaller list.

---

For anyone who wants to try this themselves, here's the timing code.

```py
import random, timeit
L = [random.random() for i in range(1000000)]

def comprehend_both():  # suggested by @max
    small = [n for n in L if n <= 0.1]
    large = [n for n in L if n > 0.1]

def append_both():   # suggested by @ignacio
    lists = small, large = [[],[]]
    for n in L: lists[n > 0.1].append(n)  # exploits False==0, True==1

def append_small_comprehend_large():  # suggested by @JustinFisher
    small = []
    large = [n for n in L if n > 0.1 or small.append(n)]

def comprehend_small_append_large():  # worse since appending more is slower
    large = []
    small = [n for n in L if n <= 0.1 or large.append(n)]

print( "C/C:", timeit.timeit("comprehend_both()",globals=globals(),number=10)) # 0.68 seconds
print( "A/A:", timeit.timeit("append_both()",globals=globals(),number=10))     # 0.80 seconds
print( "A/C:", timeit.timeit("append_small_comprehend_large()",globals=globals(),number=10)) # returns 0.52
print( "C/A:", timeit.timeit("comprehend_small_append_large()",globals=globals(),number=10)) # returns 0.68
```