# Complement of list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm wondering if there is not a way to compute the complement of a list comprehension in Python.
Something like:

```
evens = [i in range(10) if i % 2 == 0]
odds  = [i in range(10) if i % 2 != 0]
```

is there a way to get both evens and odds in one call? For a very large list, or a more expensive if statement, I think this would save a lot of time.

Comment: I would recommend looking into sets: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Comment: @NicholasFlees How would sets help?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by complement. Do you mean a way to divide a list into two lists based on a condition?

Comment: @khachik I'd like to separate the true cases from the false ones, I'd like them to be in separate containers in the end.

Comment: Sets come equipped with a `difference` method via which the complement of the set is easily accessible.

Comment: I think the best way to solve this problem is just to not use a list comprehension. It would probably scale better (what if you have a condition with more than two return values) and would be less roundabout and consequently probably more efficient.

Comment: @WaleedKhan, agree, just use one loop to fill both lists if performance is an issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Python: split a list based on a condition](http://stackoverflow.com/q/949098/1199226)

Comment: I was going to post http://pastebin.com/Eqsg8AjV, but question is already locked, unfortunately. My answer doesn't really fit linked question, but fit this one. I leave it here in case someone is interested generator/itertools based approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this question has been asked before, but I am not finding the link currently.

If you are trying to get more than one predicate and you **only want to iterate once** over the original generator, then you will have to use a simple `for` loop.

```
evens = []
odds = []

for i in xrange(10):
   if i % 2 == 0: evens.append(i)
   else: odds.append(i)
```

As @dawg pointed out, the logic inside the loop can be made more concise using clever indexing.

```
for i in xrange(10):
   (evens,odds)[i%2].append(i)
```

Comment: This does seem to be the most obvious way to get there, no sure why I didn't see it before, thanks.

Comment: How about `(evens,odds)[i%2].append(i)` instead of your if/else

Comment: @dawg, That is more concise, but arguably less readable. I will append it though.

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.groupby` is what I'd use.

```
In [1]: import itertools as it

In [2]: key = lambda i: i%2 == 0

In [3]: l = list(range(10))

In [4]: l.sort(key=key)

In [5]: [list(i[1]) for i in it.groupby(l, key=key)]
Out[5]: [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]]
```

Comment: Note that if you're concerned about the `if` condition being expensive (as the OP is), this will have far more `if` evaluations than the original one would. (Sorting requires asymptotically about `n log (n)` comparisons, and then another `n` evaluations have to be evaluated again for the groupby, compared to a total of `2n` comparisons for the original).

Comment: @DavidRobinson, AFAIK Python's built-in `sort` function calls `key` argument once for each input; so, it's just `n` conditions. And Python's `timsort` is pretty fast for long ascending/descending runs.

Answer (score 0):

I would do one of the following:

```
evens = [i in range(10) if i % 2 == 0]
odds  = [i in range(10) if i not in evens]
```

Or with better performances:

```
evens = [i in range(10) if i % 2 == 0]
evens_set = set(evens)
odds = [i in range(10) if i not in evens_set]
```

Working with `set` is better in performance, as the `not in` query costs `O(1)` instead of `O(n)` in lists

Comment: Sets would be nice here, but I'm often working with unhashable types, like a list of dicts.

Comment: If the list items are not hashable, you'll need to pay the O(n) complexity for each query on the other list, or make some workaround with hashing

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can get both True and False cases in one call, but you'd still need to split them into two lists. You could do

```
range_10 = range(10)
odds = range_10[1::2]
evens = range_10[::2]
```

but the benefit of that would be negligible. (In fact, you'd be creating three lists instead of two). You'd only want to do that if the cost of range(10) was so high that it would offset creating two lists.

Using slicing like I did should be slightly faster than using a test and explicitly appending.