# Set operation in python

Tags: python, list

I have a two list of objects say example

```
L1 = [2,3,4]
L2 = [1,2]
```

i want to have two different list.

1) matching items 
2) not matching items

I am able to get the matching element #1 like below

```
match = [x for x in L1 if x in L2]
```

but how can i get the not matching elements in a efficient way.

I can use not in but is there any other way of doing this.

Thanks ,

Comment: @PadraicCunningham no. I want just an efficient way of doing this

Answer (score 3):

You can use the various `set` methods such as [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection), [`difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference), [`symmetric_difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.symmetric_difference), and [`union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.union)

```
>>> L1 = [2,3,4]
>>> L2 = [1,2]
>>> set(L1).intersection(L2)
{2}
>>> set(L1).difference(L2)
{3, 4}
>>> set(L1).symmetric_difference(L2)
{1, 3, 4}
>>> set(L1).union(L2)
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Comment: Ahhh, you saved me. I forgot this ...:(

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by using `match`:

```
no_match = [x for x in L1 + L2 if x not in match]
```

Comment: Is there a way to get both match and not match in a single iteration meaning without using two loops like,   match , not_match = [something]

Comment: @Backtrack See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949098/python-split-a-list-based-on-a-condition)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possibility:

```
not_match=[x for x in L1 if x not in L2] + [x for x in L2 if x not in L1]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. set is best way to get matching and non matching items.

By List compression:

```
>>> L1 = [2,3,4]
>>> L2 = [1,2]
>>> [i for i in L1 if i not in  L2]
[3, 4]
>>> [i for i in L1 if i in L2]
[2]
>>> [i for x in L2 if i not in L1]
[1]
>>> [i for i in L1 if i not in  L2] +  [i for i in L2 if i not in L1]
[3, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take advantage of the [built-in type `set`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) which basically has unordered distinct elements. I also encourage you to try the shorthand notation to perform the operations `union`, `intersection`, and `difference`.

```
>>> s1 = set(L1)
>>> s2 = set(L2)
>>> s1 | s2 # union
{1, 2, 3, 4}
>>> s1 & s2 # intersection
{2}
>>> s1 - s2 # difference
{3, 4}
>>> s1 ^ s2 # symmetric difference
{1, 3, 4}
```

### A refresher of set operations from a math perspective

Suppose `A` and `B` are sets.

- The **union** of A and B is the set `A∪B = {x: x ∈ A or x ∈ B}`
- The **intersection** of A and B is the set `A∩B = {x: x ∈ A and x ∈ B}`
- The **difference** of A and B is the set `A-B = {x: x ∈ A and x ∉ B}`
- The symmetric difference of A and B is the set `A∆B = A∪B - A∩B`