# Python - How to place a whole numpy array in Queue.Queue all at once but retrieve each row separately

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

Let's say I have a 2-d numpy array with 10 rows

for example

```
array([[  23425.     ,  521331.40625],
   [  23465.     ,  521246.03125],
   [  23505.     ,  528602.8125 ],
   [  23545.     ,  531934.75   ],
   [  23585.     ,  534916.375  ],
   [  23625.     ,  544971.9375 ],
   [  23665.     ,  544707.5625 ],
   [  23705.     ,  532729.25   ],
   [  23745.     ,  540303.0625 ],
   [  23865.     ,  527971.1875 ]])
```

Is there a way to place that whole array in a queue (from python's collections) all at once, without iterating over the array and using `put()` for each row, and then be able to retrieve each row separately using the `queue.get()` function?

For example a first call to the `queue.get()` would retrieve `[23865., 527971.1875 ]` and a second call would retrieve `[23745., 540303.0625 ]`

Comment: do you want each item put in the queue or each row in your array?

Comment: The documentation page shows that only the `put()` method allows inserts, so I would say no. It also mentions a thread-safe and lock-less `deque` type on the same page which does allow you to provide an entire iterable to the constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `map` keyword to avoid iterating over the array:

`map(queue.put, myArray)`

or in python 3.x:

`list(map(queue.put, myArray))`

Comment: that's what I was looking for, should I delete the question as [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31987207/put-multiple-items-in-a-python-queue)?

Comment: I'm not sure your question is a duplicate to an existing one. I wouldn't delete it unless someone would tell you it is a duplicate

Comment: This doesn't work in Python 3 since it does lazy evaluation of maps. You would need to do some ugly thing like `list(map(queue.put, myArray))` but at that point I guess a loop is justifyable