# Using python keywords with list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How do i use a python keyword with a list comprehension, for example a del keyword in the following list comprehension.

```
[del df[x] for x in y]
```

thanks

Comment: That's not a lambda expression.

Comment: listcomps are not an universal pythonic recipe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307105/pythonic-way-to-cycle-through-purely-side-effect-based-comprehension

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions are a way to represent an expression. They cannot include statements. Use a regular loop.

```
for x in y:
    del df[x]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to delete using list comprehension. Here's how you can do that-

```
df = [x for x in df if x not in to_remove]
```

Here's an example

```
>>> df =[1,2,3]
>>> to_remove=[1,2]
>>> df = [x for x in df if x not in to_remove]
>>> df
[3]
```

Comment: it's highly unefficient. listcomps are not the ultime goal in python programming.

Comment: Sure, not contesting that, but just answering his question .

Comment: it is interesting, but i was looking for a way to use statements like `delete`  inside  list comprehensions