# partition iterator in two based on attribute

Tags: python, iteration, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I have a list of objects from which I have filtered out those that have a particular value in a single attribute:

```
import itertools 
iterator = itertools.ifilter(lambda record: record.outcome==1, list)
```

The iterator has now all objects with `outcome = 1`

However, they now differ in the value of another attribute `order=X`

I would like to partition the iterator in two: one for those objects whose `order = 1`

and another one for those with `order > 1`

Is there a another way than looping over all elements and adding them to one of the two lists / a list comprehension?

Say I have a list `l` with `obj1,obj2,obj3` as content where `obj1.order=1`, `obj2.order=2` and `obj3.order=3` I would like to yield `a # containing obj1`
 and `b # containing obj2 & obj3`

Preferably, I would like to have two other iterators so that I can do with the partial lists whatever I would like to do!

I was thinking about `itertools.groupby` but as my variable `order=X` has a number of possible values, it would give me more than two sub-iterators!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please us the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37293084/edit) on your question to show sample list with the expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: split a list based on a condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949098/python-split-a-list-based-on-a-condition)

Comment: You probably want `itertools.tee`. That will duplicate your current iterator and then you can filter one on `order == 1` and one on `order > 1`.

Comment: Not really a duplicate, that deals with lists, this deals with generators and doesn't really want to create separate lists.

Comment: Why not just use a for loop? Your lambdas are going to completely hammer the performance of ifilter so there is no advantage at all, tee is also goint to probably  more expensive than just calling list so again no advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tee` and `ifilter`.  You don't absolutely need the `tee`, but it potentially makes it more efficient if the original iterator is expensive.

```
import itertools 
iter_outcome = itertools.ifilter(lambda record: record.outcome==1, list)
a, b = itertools.tee(iter_outcome, 2)
iter_order_1 = itertools.ifilter(lambda record: record.order == 1, a)
iter_greater_1 = itertools.ifilter(lambda record: record.order > 1, b)
```

Comment: thx! What do you mean by 'expensive' => exhausive i.e. that it does not provide a possibly infinite number of objects?

Comment: If you use `tee`, it only has to do the `outcome==1` filter once for each element in the original iterator, without the `tee`, it ends up doing it twice for each element in the original iterator -- once for *each* of the secondary iterators.