# Taking a dichotomy of a list in Python per condition

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

List comprehension is pretty good for filtering a list. Is there a good way of obtaining the other half, the filtered-out part in a *single pass*? For example; take this example list:

```
>>> a = [5, 10, 45, 99]
```

The following operation selects some values from that list:

```
>>> b = [x for x in a if somecondition(x)]
>>> b
>>> [10, 45]
```

But then again, I also need the other half, so I seek something like:

```
>>> (b, c) = divideintotwo(x, somecondition)
>>> b
>>> [10, 45]
>>> c
>>> [5, 99]
```

I can write this function by myself. Though, I would rather use the one that exists, if there exists. Seems a little too basic to not have one, when Python has almost everything built-in.

Comment: See `John La Rooy` answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949098/python-split-a-list-based-on-a-condition

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find any results to my searches. So I guess there still is no such function after 7 years.

Comment: This is something which can be `composed` using an existing function in exactly 2 lines of code..you still need it to be part of standard library ? :)

Comment: @Arunmu Yes, I do. The alternative takes twice as long. I have written the function myself.