# Search for a partial string in an array of strings

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

What is the Pythonic/quick way to search for a partial string in an array and then remove that string from the array?
(I can do it with a simple loop and IF IN and rebuild two array in the loop, Asking if there is a Pythonic way/function to do this)

Example:

```
array = ['rule1','rule2','exception[type_a]','rule3','exception[type_b]']
res(,)=remove_exceptions(array,'exception')
print(res[0]) >>> ['rule1','rule2','rule3']
print(res[1]) >>> ['exception[type_a]','exception[type_b]']
```

Comment: You want to just remove them or you want to extract them from your list?

Comment: Iterating over your list and creating two new lists in the loop suite is Pythonic.  If the list elements are as you represented, you could make use of the [```str.startswith```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) method.

Comment: @Kasramvd either would work for me

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka Check out my answer.

Comment: @Kasramvd while this is what I currently (almost) use, my question was if there is a built in function/language construct (Pythonic way) to do it more efficiently (either less text/faster).

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka There is no built-in function which can does this job.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> [x for x in array if 'exception' not in x]
['rule1', 'rule2', 'rule3']
>>> [x for x in array if 'exception' in x]
['exception[type_a]', 'exception[type_b]']
```

See also: [Python: split a list based on a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949098/python-split-a-list-based-on-a-condition)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to separate your items you can do it with one loop and by preserving the items in a dictionary:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for i in array:
...     if 'exception' in i:
...         d.setdefault('exception', []).append(i)
...     else:
...         d.setdefault('other', []).append(i)
... 
>>> 
>>> d
{'exception': ['exception[type_a]', 'exception[type_b]'], 'other': ['rule1', 'rule2', 'rule3']}
```

You can access to separated items by calling the values of the dictionary:

```
>>> d.values()
[['exception[type_a]', 'exception[type_b]'], ['rule1', 'rule2', 'rule3']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Seriously, just use a `for` loop, you're trying to create *two* lists so a single comprehension won't do (i.e the top solution so far iterates *twice* over the same list).

Create two lists and append to them conditionally:

```
l1 = list()
l2 = list()
for i in array:
    l1.append(i) if 'exception' in i else l2.append(i)

print(l1)
['exception[type_a]', 'exception[type_b]']
print(l2)
['rule1', 'rule2', 'rule3']
```

Comment: "a single comprehension won't do" I feel like there must be a way to do this with co-routines and a couple of `deque`s, so that you only pass over the list once, but use the minimal possible additional memory. As against that, like you say, seriously just use a for loop. Especially when the desired result is two lists, just make two lists :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may use in-built `filter` with `lambda` function to achieve this as:

```
>>> my_array = array = ['rule1','rule2','exception[type_a]','rule3','exception[type_b]']
>>> my_string = 'exception'
>>> filter(lambda x: my_string not in x, my_array)
['rule1', 'rule2', 'rule3']
```

Comment: What makes this Pythonic?

Comment: It is Pythonic because of the usage of inbuilt functions that Python provides and perfectly suits the requirement. That says, there is no need to do list comprehension. Now my question to you: What makes it non Pythonic?

Comment: Comprehensions are (arguably) more readable. See [http://stackoverflow.com/a/3013722/1936320](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3013722/1936320)

Comment: I was curious why this was pythonic or more pythonic than just iterating over the list with a for loop and testing the elements in order to separate them.

Comment: "Readable" itself means for newbies who do not know much about Python. Whereas `pythonic` means the usage of inbuilt Python's functionality to achieve the task, and that too in most efficient way.

Comment: I meant Pythonic in the same sense @MoinuddinQuadri meant

Comment: ```...too in most efficient way...``` have you tested this against a simple for loop iteration?

Comment: There are many scenarios in which you can not use `filter` and must use `list comprehension` instead. But where you can use this, you must use it.

Comment: Pythonic is more than just using builtin functions, it includes being readable (see `python -c "import this"`). Although I agree "readable" is subjective, who said that you **must** use builtin functions over native syntax whenever you can?

Comment: @wwii: I agree `comprehensions` are comparatively faster than `filter` but time difference is of miliseconds which can be ignored. I still feel to use the inbuilt function whereever you can else what is the point of those.

Comment: @kjaquier: It is totally dependent on one's personal preference. I feel it should be used, even though it is not mandate to any one else.

Comment: I think this debate is more regarding my mention of `more pythonic` way. Removed that. :)

Comment: Specifically, the combination of `filter` with `lambda` is expressly non-Pythonic in the limited sense that [GvR has always hated it](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196). In my opinion `filter` is quite good when passed a function by name, and `filter(foo, things)` can read much better than `[thing for thing in things if foo(thing)]`. At least you don't have to choose a pointless loop variable name to type three times. But combined with a lambda most of that benefit's gone because you need to mention `thing` twice: `filter(lambda thing: something_about_thing, things)`.

Comment: In an ideal world you'd write `filter(not x.contains, my_array)`, but they're not offering us that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For list-of-strings `array` and thing-to-exclude `target`:

List comprehensions work:

```
result = [s for s in array if target not in s]
```

Or a generator comprehension for the same:

```
result = (s for s in array if target not in s)
```

(`in` is effectively a contains operator, and `not in` is the inverse.)

Alternately, use the `filter()` [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#filter) with a lambda:

```
result = filter(lambda x: target not in x,
                array)
```

Either one returns a new object, rather than modifying your original list. The list comprehension returns a list, `filter()` returns a generator but you can wrap the call in `list()` if you need random access.