# Implementation specific behavior of `groupby` and argument unpacking

Tags: python, pypy, python-internals

I'm trying to understand a quirk that I discovered in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904258/what-is-a-pythonic-and-efficient-way-to-divide-a-list-at-a-matching-element/43904461#43904461) that I wrote up earlier today.  Basically, I was yielding groups from a generator function that wrapped `itertools.groupby`.  The interesting thing that I discovered is that if I unpack the generator on the left hand side of an assignment, the last element from the generator remains.  For example:

```
# test_gb.py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

inputs = ((x > 5, x) for x in range(10))

def make_groups(inputs):
    for _, group in groupby(inputs, key=itemgetter(0)):
        yield group

a, b = make_groups(inputs)
print(list(a))
print(list(b))
```

On Cpython, this results in:

```
$ python3 ~/sandbox/test_gb.py 
[]
[(True, 9)]
```

this is the case on both CPython2.7 and CPython3.5.

On PyPy, it results in:

```
$ pypy ~/sandbox/test_gb.py 
[]
[]
```

In both cases, the first empty list ("`a`") is pretty easy to explain -- The group from `itertools` gets consumed as soon as the next element is required.  Since we didn't save those values anywhere, they're lost to the ether.

It seems to me that the `PyPy` version makes sense for the second empty list ("`b`") too ... When unpacking, we consume `b` too (because python *needs* to look for what's after to make sure that it shouldn't throw a `ValueError` for the wrong number of items to unpack).  For some reason though, the `CPython` version retains the last element from the input iterable ... Can anyone explain why this might be?

**Edit**

This is probably more or less obvious, but we can also write it as:

```
inputs = ((x > 5, x) for x in range(10))
(_, a), (_, b) = groupby(inputs, key=itemgetter(0))
print(list(a))
print(list(b))
```

and get the same results ...

Comment: We have changed PyPy to behave like CPython.  I know this is not really answering the question "why": just copying the exact algorithm from CPython into PyPy, instead of using a version reconstructed from the docs, ensures we get the same results.

Comment: The behavior seems a bit broken.  I think you may want to ask this question in a CPython issue report.  Maybe it will be fixed for the next 3.7 release; or maybe someone will find a reason for why the current behavior is better; or maybe your issue will remain open forever.

Comment: For anyone else interested, It looks like the pypy change was made in [this commit](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/commits/6093ff1a44e6b17f09db83aa80aea562a738c286)

Comment: And I've reported it as a bug to the CPython folks.  You can track it at http://bugs.python.org/issue30346

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `groupby` object handles the bookkeeping and the `grouper` objects just reference their `key` and the parent `groupby` object:

```c
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    PyObject *it;          /* iterator over the input sequence */
    PyObject *keyfunc;     /* the second argument for the groupby function */
    PyObject *tgtkey;      /* the key for the current "grouper" */
    PyObject *currkey;     /* the key for the current "item" of the iterator*/
    PyObject *currvalue;   /* the plain value of the current "item" */
} groupbyobject;

typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    PyObject *parent;      /* the groupby object */
    PyObject *tgtkey;      /* the key value for this grouper object. */
} _grouperobject;
```

Since you're not iterating the `grouper` object when you unpack the `groupby` object I'll ignore them for now. So what's interesting is what happens in the `groupby` when you call `next` on it:

```c
static PyObject *
groupby_next(groupbyobject *gbo)
{
    PyObject *newvalue, *newkey, *r, *grouper;

    /* skip to next iteration group */
    for (;;) {
        if (gbo->currkey == NULL)
            /* pass */;
        else if (gbo->tgtkey == NULL)
            break;
        else {
            int rcmp;

            rcmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(gbo->tgtkey, gbo->currkey, Py_EQ);
            if (rcmp == 0)
                break;
        }

        newvalue = PyIter_Next(gbo->it);
        if (newvalue == NULL)
            return NULL;   /* just return NULL, no invalidation of attributes */
        newkey = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(gbo->keyfunc, newvalue, NULL);

        gbo->currkey = newkey;
        gbo->currvalue = newvalue;
    }
    gbo->tgtkey = gbo->currkey;

    grouper = _grouper_create(gbo, gbo->tgtkey);
    r = PyTuple_Pack(2, gbo->currkey, grouper);
    return r;
}
```

I removed all the irrelevant exception handling code and removed or simplified pure reference counting stuff. The interesting thing here is that when you reach the end of the iterator the `gbo->currkey`, `gbo->currvalue` and `gbo->tgtkey` aren't set to `NULL`, they will still point to the last encountered values (the last item of the iterator) because it just `return NULL` when `PyIter_Next(gbo->it) == NULL`.

After this finished you have your two `grouper` objects. The first one will have a `tgtvalue` of `False` and the second with `True`. Let's have a look what happens when you call `next` on these `grouper`s:

```c
static PyObject *
_grouper_next(_grouperobject *igo)
{
    groupbyobject *gbo = (groupbyobject *)igo->parent;
    PyObject *newvalue, *newkey, *r;
    int rcmp;

    if (gbo->currvalue == NULL) {
        /* removed because irrelevant. */
    }

    rcmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(igo->tgtkey, gbo->currkey, Py_EQ);
    if (rcmp <= 0)
        /* got any error or current group is end */
        return NULL;

    r = gbo->currvalue;  /* this accesses the last value of the groupby object */
    gbo->currvalue = NULL;
    gbo->currkey = NULL;

    return r;
}
```

So remember `currvalue` is **not** `NULL`, so the first `if` branch isn't interesting. For your first grouper it compares the `tgtkey` of the `grouper` and the `groupby` object and sees that they differ and it will immediatly `return NULL`. So you got an empty list.

For the second iterator the `tgtkey`s are identical, so it will **return the `currvalue` of the `groupby` object** (which is the last encountered value in the iterator!), but this time it will set the `currvalue` and `currkey` of the `groupby` object to `NULL`.

---

Switching back to python: The really interesting quirks happen if you have a `grouper` with the same `tgtkey` as the last group in your `groupby`:

```py
import itertools

>>> inputs = [(x > 5, x) for x in range(10)] + [(False, 10)]
>>> (_, g1), (_, g2), (_, g3) = itertools.groupby(inputs, key=lambda x: x[0])
>>> list(g1)
[(False, 10)]
>>> list(g3)
[]
```

That one element in `g1` didn't belong to the first group at all - but because the `tgtkey` of the first grouper object is `False` and the last `tgtkey` is `False` the first grouper thought it belongs into the first group. It also invalidated the `groupby` object so the third group is now empty.

---

All the code was taken from [the Python source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L11) but shortened.