# rearrange the characters so that all consonants appear before the vowels

Tags: python, string

write a python function so that

words at odd position:reverse it

words at even position:rearrange the characters so that all consonants 
    appear before the vowels and their order should not change

input:the sun rises in the east
    output:eht snu sesir ni eht stea

I have reverse the string but unable to do the rearrangement of characters.
    Can we use append and join function or need to swap at end.
    Basically rotation of string is done so how we can acheive that.

```
def encrypt_sentence(sentence):
    vowel_set = set("aeiouAEIOU")
    final_list=[]
    word=sentence.split()
    for i in range(0,len(word)):
        if((i%2)==0):
            final_list.append(word[i][::-1])
        else:
           final_list.append("".join(c for c in word if c not in vowel_set))
 print(final_list)                   
encrypt_sentence("the sun rises in the east")
```

Comment: have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/q/949098/5986907

Comment: your function would be better to `return final_list` assign that to a variable and then print from there, its not good practice to have your function `print` and have no `return`

Comment: @vash_the_stampede thanku for letting me know.I will make sure in future to write return instead of print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would iterate through the letters keeping track of the vowels and consonants, and then use join at the end.

```
def encrypt_sentence(sentence):
    vowel_set = set("aeiouAEIOU")
    final_list=[]
    word=sentence.split()
    for i in range(0,len(word)):
        if((i%2)==0):
            final_list.append(word[i][::-1])
        else:  # do rearrangement
            vowels = list()
            consonants = list()
            for letter in word[i]:
                if letter in vowel_set:
                    vowels.append(letter)
                else:
                    consonants.append(letter)
            new_string = "".join(consonants) + "".join(vowels)
            final_list.append(new_string)
    return final_list
```

Comment: thanku @andrew  it works!! I have been solving this problem for 3 hours.Thanks once again for spending your precious time on my problem

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

try using two list comprehensions:

```
word='testing'
vov=[x if x in vowel_set else '' for x in word]
cons=[x if x not in vowel_set else '' for x in word]
('').join(cons+vov)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def encrypt_sentence(sentence):
    vowel=set("AEIOUaeiou")
    s1=sentence
    var=""

    li = list(sentence.split(" "))
    for i in range(len(li)):
        var=li[i]
        if(i%2==0):
            var=var[::-1]
            li[i]=var

        else:
            t=""
            t2=""
            for j in var:
                if(j in vowel):
                    t2=t2+j
                else:
                    t=t+j
            t=t+t2
            li[i]=t
    var2=""
    for i in range(len(li)):
        var2=var2+li[i]
        if(i != len(li)-1):
            var2=var2+" "
    return var2


sentence="The sun rises in the east"
encrypted_sentence=encrypt_sentence(sentence)
print(encrypted_sentence)
```

Comment: Could you explain why this solution solves the question? Only pasting code makes it hard to why this solution has been chosen.

Comment: @MaartenDev the solution is very easy to understand