# python cut a list by certain id

Tags: python

I have a list contains dates and id, for example:

```
olist = ['20191101_01.csv','20191101_02.csv','20191101_03.csv','20191101_04.csv','20191102_01.csv','20191102_02.csv','20191102_03.csv','20191102_04.csv','20191103_01.csv','20191103_02.csv','20191103_03.csv','20191103_04.csv']
```

and I want to cut them by ids, for example:

```
nlist = [['20191101_01.csv','20191102_01.csv','20191103_01.csv','20191104_01.csv'],['20191101_02.csv','20191102_02.csv','20191103_02.csv','20191104_02.csv']......]
```

is there a simple and clean way to do it?

Comment: This should probably answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949098/python-split-a-list-based-on-a-condition

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service.   You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer for solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a dict. You can then achieve it o(n) time

```
olist = ['20191101_01.csv','20191101_02.csv','20191101_03.csv','20191101_04.csv','20191102_01.csv','20191102_02.csv','20191102_03.csv','20191102_04.csv','20191103_01.csv','20191103_02.csv','20191103_03.csv','20191103_04.csv']
parsed_dict = {}
for el in olist:
  key = el.split('_')[1]
  if parsed_dict.get(key) is None:
    parsed_dict[key] = [el]
  else:
    parsed_dict[key].append(el)

print(parsed_dict)
```

**edit, updated according to wwii's comment:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

olist = ['20191101_01.csv','20191101_02.csv','20191101_03.csv','20191101_04.csv','20191102_01.csv','20191102_02.csv','20191102_03.csv','20191102_04.csv','20191103_01.csv','20191103_02.csv','20191103_03.csv','20191103_04.csv']
parsed_dict = defaultdict(list)
for el in olist:
  key = el.split('_')[1]
  parsed_dict[key].append(el)

print(parsed_dict)
```

Comment: You could use a `collections.defaultdict(list)` to avoid the `if/else`.

Comment: @wwii or [**`dict.setdefault`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), e.g. `parsed_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(el)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and a [list compreension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), i.e.:

```
from collections import defaultdict
olist = ['20191101_01.csv','20191101_02.csv','20191101_03.csv','20191101_04.csv','20191102_01.csv','20191102_02.csv','20191102_03.csv','20191102_04.csv','20191103_01.csv','20191103_02.csv','20191103_03.csv','20191103_04.csv']
d = defaultdict(list)
[d[x.split("_")[1].split(".")[0]].append(x) for x in olist]
print(dict(d))
```

---

```
{'01': ['20191101_01.csv', '20191102_01.csv', '20191103_01.csv'], '02': ['20191101_02.csv', '20191102_02.csv', '20191103_02.csv'], '03': ['20191101_03.csv', '20191102_03.csv', '20191103_03.csv'], '04': ['20191101_04.csv', '20191102_04.csv', '20191103_04.csv']}
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/0b50a1f4d1)

Answer (score 0):

could also use pandas for this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'files':olist})

df['grouper'] = df['files'].str.split('_',expand=True)[1]
nlist = df.groupby('grouper')['files'].agg(list).tolist()
```

output:

```
[['20191101_01.csv', '20191102_01.csv', '20191103_01.csv'], ['20191101_02.csv', '20191102_02.csv', '20191103_02.csv'], ['20191101_03.csv', '20191102_03.csv', '20191103_03.csv'], ['20191101_04.csv', '20191102_04.csv', '20191103_04.csv']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the list using the two character id and then group it using [**`itertools.groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
from itertools import groupby

olist = ['20191101_01.csv','20191101_02.csv','20191101_03.csv','20191101_04.csv',
         '20191102_01.csv','20191102_02.csv','20191102_03.csv','20191102_04.csv',
         '20191103_01.csv','20191103_02.csv','20191103_03.csv','20191103_04.csv']

file_id = lambda filename: filename[-6:-4]

slist = sorted(olist, key=file_id)

result = [list(value) for key, value in groupby(slist, key=file_id)]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[['20191101_01.csv', '20191102_01.csv', '20191103_01.csv'],
 ['20191101_02.csv', '20191102_02.csv', '20191103_02.csv'],
 ['20191101_03.csv', '20191102_03.csv', '20191103_03.csv'],
 ['20191101_04.csv', '20191102_04.csv', '20191103_04.csv']]
```