# What is the fastest way to split a list into multiple sublists based on several conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, performance

What is the fastest way to split a list into multiple sublists based on conditions? Each condition represents a separate sublist.

One way to split a `listOfObjects` into sublists (three sublists for demonstration, but more are possible):

```
listOfObjects = [.......]
l1, l2, l3 = [], [], []
for l in listOfObjects:
    if l.someAttribute == "l1":
        l1.append(l)
    elif l.someAttribute == "l2":
        l2.append(l)
    else:
        l3.append(l)
```

This way does not seem pythonic at all and also takes quite some time. Are there faster approaches, e.g. using `map`?

There is a similar question, but with only one condition, i.e., two result lists: [How to split a list based on a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949098/split-a-list-based-on-a-condition)

Comment: Would you want to put categories other `l1` and `l2` into one single list? or would each category go into a separate list?

Comment: One separate list per category

Comment: Please mention that in the question itself. It would be helpful for future readers. Comments might get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You could [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here for mapping.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for l in listOfObjects:
    d[l.someAttribute].append(l)

out = d.values() 
l1 , l2, l3 = d['l1'], d['l2'], d['l3']
```

`d` would be of the form.

```
{ 
  attr1 : [...],
  attr2 : [...],
  ...
  attrn : [...]
}
```

Comment: I really like your answer since it's a readable and scalable solution. Now to the second part of my question: Could you provide some speed tests?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I assumed it was just for demonstration. I thought OP wanted to split(group) them based on attribute value. My bad.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I delete my answer if OP wants a default category too.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I've undeleted my answer after OP clarified in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70768463/fastest-way-to-split-list-into-multiple-sublists-based-on-several-conditions/70768539#comment125108478_70768463) that they want *"one separate list per category"*.

Answer (score 1):

That similar question's answer is amazing. I haven't thought about that for splitting... Anyway, you can do something similar but it would be less readable:

```
for l in listOfObjects:
    (l3, l2, l1)[(l.someAttribute == "l1")*2 or l.someAttribute == "l2"].append(l)
```

This will work for any boolean conditions. `or` returns first truthy value (or False). `True==1`, so we add *2 for the index that we want to be equal to 2.

But as I said, it's not really readable. And not scalable.

As for speed: `or` is short-circuiting, returns first truthy value, so the check of conditions should be similar to your approach. You might want to keep the lookup tuple defined outside of the loop.

---

And more readable thing using dict because your conditions are based on equality (note: attribute you want also has to be hashable)

```py
lookup = {"l1": l1, "l2": l2}
for l in listOfObjects:
    lookup.get(l.someAttribute, l3).append(l)
```

`dict.get` gets default value as second - so it's perfect for our else catchall.

In terms of speed: Dictionary lookup will have only one check, as opposed to a chain of `or` conditions of chain of `if`s

Comment: OP mentioned *"three sublists for demonstration, but **more are possible**"* scaling up would be very difficult with the above approach.

Comment: That's why there's also dict approach in there. ;)

Comment: How would you scale your dictionary version? Unless you know all the attribute values beforehand?

Comment: OP demonstrated ifs with equality, suggesting they know the values from somewhere.+ considering their use of `else`, I assumed they want to know only some of them and then a catchall for the rest. If they don't want the catchall, then yes, defaultdict is better. | But even if we come to the conclusion that it's not the best solution for this case, I'll leave my answer in there, in case people with similar problems come in here. :)

Comment: Got you. :) The question is unclear whether OP wants the "default" category. I hope they clarify the question.