# How to split a list into two based on a value?

Tags: python, split

I am trying to create a function which can separate a list into two new lists based on a value (in this case 3.5).

The code I have tried to make so far makes a list of the first values in  the main list (the ones I want to compare). This list is [1,1,3,1,4,4,5,1] I now want to create two lists. This would be [1,1,3,1,1] and [4,4,5]. However, I cannot use > to compare the different values in the list and am unsure how to do so.

Comment: in your code, `my_list` is a list of tuples, and you don't pass any arguments to your function?

Comment: @SuperStew sorry I don't understand

Comment: Your question is about how to split a list, but you have a list of tuples. Those are different, do you want to split each tuple or what? Also you just use `my_list` in your function without passing it in as an argument. Your function won't (or shouldn't) know what outside variables are unless they're global.

Comment: wait so you want to sort the tuples into 2 lists, based on their first value only?

Comment: yes, that is what i want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I partition (split up, divide) a list based on a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949098/how-can-i-partition-split-up-divide-a-list-based-on-a-condition)

Answer (score 1):

As I said above, I'm confused about what your code is trying to do, but you can split a list like this.

```
my_list=[1,1,3,1,4,4,5,1]
my_val=3.5 #value to split on 

list1=[x for x in my_list if x>my_val]
list2=[x for x in my_list if x<my_val]
```

EDIT

To make this work for a list of tuples, based on their first value, you can do the same but with a slight modification

```
my_list = [(1, 4, 3, 0), 
           (1, 7, 6, 0),
           (3, 8, 7, 0), 
           (1, 1, 9, 0), 
           (4, 1, 1, 0), 
           (4, 3, 8, 1), 
           (5, 4, 2, 1), 
           (1, 7, 7, 1)]
list1=[x for x in my_list if x[0]>my_val]
list2=[x for x in my_list if x[0]<my_val]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `itertools` module documentation provides a series of [recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) for common tasks. One of them is a `partition` function.

```
from itertools import tee, filterfalse


def partition(pred, iterable):
    "Use a predicate to partition entries into false entries and true entries"
    # partition(is_odd, range(10)) --> 0 2 4 6 8   and  1 3 5 7 9
    t1, t2 = tee(iterable)
    return filterfalse(pred, t1), filter(pred, t2)


my_list=[1,1,3,1,4,4,5,1]
t1, t2 = partition(lambda x: x > 3.5, my_list)

list1 = list(t1)  # [1, 1, 3, 1, 1]
list2 = list(t2)  # [4, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Whipping out itertools and lambda function for a relatively easy sorting task....mate thats a bit much no?

Comment: Not really, no.

Comment: you do you, but doesn't seem very pythonic.

Comment: The benefit here is that `partition` itself is a constant-time operation. No iteration is performed until you actually iterate over `t1` and/or `t2`, and that iteration is lazy.

Comment: I'm not claiming this is *always* the best solution, but for some uses cases it could be.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function to split your list for a value.

```
def split_list(val, _list):
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    for _x in _list:
        (list1 if _x <= val else list2).append(_x)
    return list1, list2

# Your example
print(split_list(3.5, [1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 5, 1]))

#brings output
#([1, 1, 3, 1, 1], [4, 4, 5])
```

And call it repeated for a data set as you said

```
# For a data set like yours
my_list = [(1, 4, 3, 0),
           (1, 7, 6, 0),
           (3, 8, 7, 0),
           (1, 1, 9, 0),
           (4, 1, 1, 0),
           (4, 3, 8, 1),
           (5, 4, 2, 1),
           (1, 7, 7, 1)]
my_list_1 = []
my_list_2 = []
for x in my_list:
    g, le = split_list(3.5, x)
    my_list_1.append(g)
    my_list_2.append(le)

print(my_list_1)
print(my_list_2)
# Separates the list to 
[[1, 3, 0], [1, 0], [3, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [3, 1], [2, 1], [1, 1]]
[[4], [7, 6], [8, 7], [9], [4], [4, 8], [5, 4], [7, 7]]
```