# Compare and iterate over two 2D arrays

Tags: python

I have two 2D arrays like these:

```
mix = [[1,'Blue'],[2,'Black'],[3,'Black'],[4,'Red']]

possibilities = [[1,'Black'],[1,'Red'],[1,'Blue'],[1,'Yellow'],
         [2,'Green'],[2,'Black'],
         [3,'Black'],[3,'Pink'],
         [4,'White'],[4,'Blue'],[4,'Yellow'],
         [5,'Purple'],[5,'Blue']
        ]
```

I want to loop through the **possibilities** list, find the exact index in which it matches the **mix** list, then append the correct mix into a new list.**IF it does not match the MIX list, append into a "bad list" and then move on to the next iteration.** For now this is the idea I had ---- note it totally DOES NOT work! :)

```
i = 0
j = 0
bad_guess = []
correct_guess = []
while i < len(mix):
    while possibilities[j] != mix[i]:
        j += 1
    if possibilities[j] == mix[i]:
        i +=1
        correct_guess.append(possibilities[j])
        j = 0
    elif possibilities[j] != mix[i]:
        bad_guess.append(mix[i])
        break
```

**Output**
Basically the output I would want for this example is:

```
correct_guess = [[1,'Blue'],[2,'Black'],[3,'Black'],[5,'Purple']
bad_guess = [4,'Red']
```

Comment: Why is (4, red) "bad" and (5, purple) "correct"?

Comment: How does your approach not work? Why is `bad_guess` not a nested list in the expected result? By the way, those are lists, not arrays. The terms mean different things in python.

Comment: Hello guys, my deepest apologies as I forgot to add the [5,'Purple'] in the MIX list. Also, sorry for mistaking lists and arrays. Thanks for pointing these things out, it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is [often the case in Python](https://treyhunner.com/2016/04/how-to-loop-with-indexes-in-python/), you don't actually have to muck about with indices at all to do this.

First, here is a simple solution using your existing data structure. Iterate over `mix`, and append each item to the appropriate list, depending on whether it's in `possibilities` or not. (This is the same idea presented in [this answer to "How to split a list based on a condition?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/950591/12975140))

```
mix = [
    [1, 'Blue'],
    [2, 'Black'],
    [3, 'Black'],
    [4, 'Red'],
]

possibilities = [
    [1, 'Black'], [1, 'Red'], [1, 'Blue'], [1, 'Yellow'],
    [2, 'Green'], [2, 'Black'],
    [3, 'Black'], [3, 'Pink'],
    [4, 'White'], [4, 'Blue'], [4, 'Yellow'],
    [5, 'Purple'], [5, 'Blue'],
]

correct_guesses = []
bad_guesses = []

for item in mix:
    if item in possibilities:
        correct_guesses.append(item)
    else:
        bad_guesses.append(item)

print(correct_guesses)
print(bad_guesses)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 'Blue'], [2, 'Black'], [3, 'Black']]
[[4, 'Red']]
```

---

However, this does a lot of unnecessary looping. Each time you check `item in possibilities`, the code has to iterate over `possibilities` (which is a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)) to see whether or not `item` is there.

As others have commented, the issue here is your data structure. Instead of a list, `possibilities` could be a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Checking whether a dictionary has a given key, or accessing the value associated with a given key, is O(n); essentially it's "instant" instead of having to go look for it.

```
possibilities = {
    1: ['Black', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow'],
    2: ['Green', 'Black'],
    3: ['Black', 'Pink'],
    4: ['White', 'Blue', 'Yellow'],
    5: ['Purple', 'Blue']
}
```

Here each key is an integer, and each value is a list of the colors that number allows. Then your `for` loop would look like this, checking if the color is one allowed for that number

```
for item in mix:
    number, color = item
    if color in possibilities[number]:
        correct_guesses.append(item)
    else:
        bad_guesses.append(item)
```

Do you see the problem, though? We're still doing the same thing: using `in` on a list. We could turn each of those lists into a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) instead, which can much more efficiently check whether or not it contains something:

```
possibilities = {
    1: {'Black', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow'},
    2: {'Green', 'Black'},
    3: {'Black', 'Pink'},
    4: {'White', 'Blue', 'Yellow'},
    5: {'Purple', 'Blue'}
}
```

The `for` loop would remain the same.

---

With all that in mind, here's a complete solution. I've also changed the two-item lists to [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), which serves no functional difference in this case, but is more idiomatic.

```
mix = [
    (1, 'Blue'),
    (2, 'Black'),
    (3, 'Black'),
    (4, 'Red'),
]

possibilities = {
    1: {'Black', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow'},
    2: {'Green', 'Black'},
    3: {'Black', 'Pink'},
    4: {'White', 'Blue', 'Yellow'},
    5: {'Purple', 'Blue'}
}

correct_guesses = []
bad_guesses = []

for item in mix:
    number, color = item
    if color in possibilities[number]:
        correct_guesses.append(item)
    else:
        bad_guesses.append(item)

print(correct_guesses)
print(bad_guesses)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'Blue'), (2, 'Black'), (3, 'Black')]
[(4, 'Red')]
```

---

P.S. Ideally you'd change how you generate `possibilities` in the first place, but if you're faced with a situation where you have the lists of lists, and want to convert it into the corresponding dictionary of sets, this would work:

```
possibilities_list = [
    [1, 'Black'], [1, 'Red'], [1, 'Blue'], [1, 'Yellow'],
    [2, 'Green'], [2, 'Black'],
    [3, 'Black'], [3, 'Pink'],
    [4, 'White'], [4, 'Blue'], [4, 'Yellow'],
    [5, 'Purple'], [5, 'Blue'],
]

possibilities_dict = {}

for num, color in possibilities_list:
    if num in possibilities_dict:
        possibilities_dict[num].add(color)
    else:
        possibilities_dict[num] = {color}
```

Or using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to simplify the logic:

```
from collections import defaultdict

possibilities_dict = defaultdict(set)

for num, color in possibilities_list:
    possibilities_dict[num].add(color)
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your feedback. I tested it all, every solutions totally worked, although I need to understand a bit better how dictionaries work and how to properly convert 2D lists into dictionaries. Appreciate you taking your time to write this lengthy answer, can't thank you enough. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Romain_NewPython Ideally you'd make the change where you create `possibilities` in the first place, in order to store it in a more useful form. But I've added an edit that may be helpful if you don't control in what form you get it.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
mix = [[1,'Blue'],[2,'Black'],[3,'Black'],[4,'Red']]

possibilities = [[1,'Black'],[1,'Red'],[1,'Blue'],[1,'Yellow'],
         [2,'Green'],[2,'Black'],
         [3,'Black'],[3,'Pink'],
         [4,'White'],[4,'Blue'],[4,'Yellow'],
         [5,'Purple'],[5,'Blue']
        ]

bad_guess = []
correct_guess = []
for i in mix:
    if i in possibilities:
        correct_guess.append(i)
    else:
        bad_guess.append(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways of solving this. The simple way is to loop through the lists, but that's not very pythonic. You can remove the inner loop using a containment check:

```
bad_guess = []
correct_guess = []
for item in mix:
    if item in possibilities:
        correct_guess.append(item)
    else:
        bad_guess.append(item)
```

The `in` operator is going to do a linear search through `possibilities` at every iteration. For a small list like this, it's probably fine, but for something larger, you will want a faster lookup.

Faster lookup is offered in sets. Unfortunately, sets can not contain non-hashable types such as lists. The good news is that they can contain tuples:

```
mix = [tuple(item) for item in mix]
possibilities = {tuple(item) for item in possibilities}
bad_guess = []
correct_guess = []
for item in mix:
    if item in possibilities:
        correct_guess.append(item)
    else:
        bad_guess.append(item)
```

Another way to get the same result is to first sort `mix` by whether an item appears in `possibilities` or not, and then use `itertools.groupby` to create the output lists. This approach is fun to parse, but is not particularly legible, and therefore not recommended:

```
key = lambda item: item in possibilities
bad_guess, correct_guess = (list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(mix, key=key), key=key))
```

This last method is more algorithmically complex than the set lookup because sorting is an O(N log N) operation, while lookup in a set is O(1).

Answer (score 1):

```
mix = {1:'Blue' , 2:'Black' , 3:'Black' , 4:'Red'}

possibilities = [[1,'Black'],[1,'Red'],[1,'Blue'],[1,'Yellow'],
     [2,'Green'],[2,'Black'],
     [3,'Black'],[3,'Pink'],
     [4,'White'],[4,'Blue'],[4,'Yellow'],
     [5,'Purple'],[5,'Blue']
    ]

for poss in possibilities:
    if (mix[poss[0]] = poss[1]) & (poss not in bad_guess):
        bad_guess.append(poss)
    elif poss not in good_guess:
        good_guess.append(poss)
```

you could try making the mix list a dictionary instead so you dont need to iterate over it

Comment: Thanks! Again with the dictionaries! I really need to consider them. It worked just fine. :)

Comment: sometimes theyre use is obvious, other times it seems like a stroke of genius to use them. Im about a year into this and am now seeing lots uses for them in recursion and algorithms