# Separating elements from a list in Python depending on a condition

Tags: python, functional-programming

I have a list of elements and want to **separate** the elements of the list by a certain condition.

A simple example is a list of numbers and i want to separate the odd from the even ones.
For that could use the `filter` builtin like so:

```py
def is_even(x):
    # ...

l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

even = list(filter(is_even, l))
odd = list(filter(not is_even, l))
```

That is a bit error prone if the condition is a bit more complex, because i repeat myself twice in the `filter` functions. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) has a recipe exactly for that:

> ```
> from itertools import tee, filterfalse
> def partition(pred, iterable):
>     "Use a predicate to partition entries into false entries and true entries"
>     # partition(is_odd, range(10)) --> 0 2 4 6 8   and  1 3 5 7 9
>     t1, t2 = tee(iterable)
>     return filterfalse(pred, t1), filter(pred, t2)
> ```

Usage:

```
odd, even = partition(is_even, l)
```

You can convert them to lists, but I suggest leaving them as iterators.

Comment: A nice solution, thank you. Can i assume the tee-part is only needed if you have an iterator (i.e. something you can iterate over only once) - when you have a list, just providing the list to filter and filterfalse will do the trick as well, right?

Comment: @BastianVenthur yup.

Comment: @BastianVenthur but definitely use the `tee` technique so `partition` can be general enough for use with any iterable input

Answer (score 1):

My approach to this is you can make two lists one named [ even ] and the other named [ odd ] and you can make a for loop to filter the original list and add the even value to the [ even ] list and the odd value to the [ odd ] list:

```py
original_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

even_list = []
odd_list = []

for value in original_list:
    if value % 2 == 0:
        even_list.append(value)

    else:
        odd_list.append(value)
```

something like this would work fine and I hope this solves your question ✨

Answer (score 1):

A generator version, to be used when `pred` does heavy computation and you wish to run on iterables instead of sequences.

Does not hold all values in memory, runs `pred` only once for every object.

```
from collections import deque
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, Iterable
_T = TypeVar('_T')

def iter_split(pred: Callable[[_T], bool],
               iterable: Iterable[_T]) -> tuple[Iterable[_T], Iterable[_T]]:
    """Split an iterable into two iterables based on a predicate.
    
    The predicate will only be called once per element.
    
    Returns:
        A tuple of two iterables, the first containing all elements for which
        the predicate returned True, the second containing all elements for
        which the predicate returned False.
    """
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    true_values: deque[_T] = deque()
    false_values: deque[_T] = deque()
    
    def true_generator():
        while True:
            while true_values:
                yield true_values.popleft()
            
            for item in iterator:
                if pred(item):
                    yield item
                    break
                false_values.append(item)
            else:
                break
            
    def false_generator():
        while True:
            while false_values:
                yield false_values.popleft()
            
            for item in iterator:
                if not pred(item):
                    yield item
                    break
                true_values.append(item)
            else:
                break

    return true_generator(), false_generator()
```

---

A thread-proof example for the `true_generator()` (lock is shared between both gens):

```
lock = RLock() # RLock in case pred uses a generator.

def true_generator():
    lock.acquire()
    while True:
        while true_values:
            lock.release()
            yield true_values.popleft()
            lock.acquire()
        
        for item in iterator:
            try:
                res = pred(item)
            except BaseException:
                lock.release()
                raise
            if res:
                lock.release()
                yield item
                lock.acquire()
                break
            false_values.append(item)
        else:
            break
    lock.release()
```

Comment: I like it. Only potential issue I see is if I request a value from the true_generator and it goes into its for-loop, but it gets interrupted by another thread where I request a value from the false_generator, then that second request might find and append true-values that the first request will miss.

Comment: Or I guess instead of threads, the `pred(item)` call could also trip it up if it requests a value from the false_generator. But I doubt that's a realistic use case :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy It's quite easy to add a lock to these

Comment: [Here's mine](https://tio.run/##XZBLigMxDET3PoU2A3bwIunehMCcJThp9cTgH7ICyel7/GkPTLwwklX1Cjm9@RHDfE60bStFD5aROEaXwfoUiYERNdyjT4Q5i6aJCclwpD8JPfmhIUS@CrHgCjk5y9fiWOzdMMpa6YY2N4fqIqAcy6f6NtVrhu8aJIdEw6yaqDpzGXqT5B5TywGc1ZAVVqJpxzRXnxQTVsDYQLbYou/j1bj8OZ96Rl2nQfcMQn5S6EC9G4X41xbO5@rO@Nti4HWp3wOvrwInE35Qno6FKxLZwPLQKGp0Haa27Rc), btw. I also only compute each predicate value only once, but my two `compress` iterators still both *iterate* over all input values and predicate values and both truth-test all predicate truth values. Yours doesn't, that's what I like.

Comment: @KellyBundy boop

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to run the predicate twice, you can create 2 lists like so:

```
def split_predicate(pred, iterable):
    """Split an iterable into two lists based on a predicate.
    
    The predicate will only be called once per element.
    
    Returns:
        A tuple of two lists, the first containing all elements for which
        the predicate returned True, the second containing all elements for
        which the predicate returned False."""
    t1, t2 = [], []
    for item in iterable:
        (t1 if pred(item) else t2).append(item)
    return t1, t2
```

Comment: I'm interested in the generators version.

Comment: I have an idea how to do it but don't like it much. Btw, might want to post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/949098/12671057) if it's something new (I think that's the "canonical").

Comment: @KellyBundy Done. Keep in mind it'll be slower for than the other 2, unless both the iterable is long, and predicate is complex. Otherwise `partition` or `split_predicate` should be used respectively.