# How to partition a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Many languages provide a standard library which provides a dictionary or binary tree map type. Many of these data structure implementations provide a function to split the data structure into a pair of data structures based on some condition.

This is known as a partition operation. Rust calls it "split off". C++ `map` types have "lower bound" and "upper bound" operation for comparison to keys. The standard library also provides a "partition" operation which exists in `std::algorithm`.

I can't see an ideomatic way of doing this in Python. I have managed to come up with a manual way of doing it, but I don't really like this code, because it doesn't split a `dict` into two parts, but splits part of it and then splits another part of it, resulting in fragile (and duplicated) code.

```
map = {
   ...
}

map_part_1 = {
    key: value for key, value in map.items() if <condition>
}

map_part_2 = {
    key: value for key, value in map.items() if not <condition>
}
```

Not great, right? Is there a better way?

Comment: The first and third certainly don't. Those are different questions. I can't understand the second question because it's not written in a clear way. I have no idea what is being asked.

Comment: Anyhow -- your current `dict_partition` is close enough to what I'd write that I'm not sure a new answer is warranted -- main changes I'd make would be about reducing duplication; no need to run `condition` twice for a given k/v pair. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/949490/14122, which is readily adapted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a shorter helper (than your answer's) which evaluates the condition only once for each item:

```py
def dict_partition(input: dict, condition: Callable[[Any, Any], bool]) -> tuple[dict, dict]:
    dicts = ({}, {})
    for key, value in input.items():
        dicts[condition(key, value)][key] = value
    return dicts
```

If you want to maintain the ordering of the first dict being the dictionary of true evaluated conditions, and the second dictionary being the dictionary of false evaluated conditions, replace `return dicts` with `return dicts[::-1]`.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pZLfSsMwFMbBy176BOeuLXRCOwUJThAfo5SStakLtklIT6dD9iTe7EbfaYLvYv6MWrZdCBbaJl_yO-c7J3n_VBtcSbHbQ6NlB7hRXDwB75TUCI-0bemyZQk8iM3HgM3sdv9dswZqXmGpqEaOXIqICzUgcWoClRS1k8nI57nhXZAigaWUbRHD7B5wUGbNU_ZbkADMY4c9LOBtm5jXSY3U8MxMiDVtBwZcgEt5xZF1fRR7bmTz0UL0C8VFbiaFieumjtAMBy0OECGztPBFfl1c2iqR9VgelWpyOdTltybH1CmBUAoWJqOSGQVf5ESZW2Wl2XTXtdEaOeiJdGMlvmahU7Y-Y-ScpL5VZRab5OeOIYGWdsuaTvpF7BjuYB4HY4PLtGSvilXI6j9WMfXiLZyP8J8aad8zc--8QVgsjq0mEB7WGspbd0BQ0f4QZEpnI52d0NkJHZw96kBpLjAKa9uQ2F-N3c7_fwA)

Comment: Wow - cool - how does it work? I guess condition returns either 0 or 1? (Assuming it returns a `bool`?)

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant You declared it as `bool`, and `False == 0` and `True == 1`.

Comment: Then you reverse the list using `[::-1]`?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Not list but tuple, yes, because you want the true-dict first. I considered doing `not condition(...)` instead, but that would cost time for each item instead of just once.

Comment: Ok cool, actually the order doesn't matter to me personally in the case of this use context - false coming first is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something but you can do this in one loop:

```py
def dict_partition(dct, condition):
    d1, d2 = {}, {}
    for k, v in dct.items():
        if condition(v):
            d1[k] = v
        else:
            d2[k] = v
    return d1, d2


dct = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4}
print(dict_partition(dct, lambda x: x > 2))
```

Prints:

```
({'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2})
```

---

If you want to modify input dictionary, you can use `dict.pop`:

```py
dct1 = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4}
dct2 = {k: dct1.pop(k) for k in [*dct1] if dct1[k] > 2}

print(dct1)
print(dct2)
```

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
{'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced this is the best approach. It works, but requires writing a helper function.

```
def dict_partition(input: dict, condition: Callable[[Any, Any], bool]) -> tuple[dict, dict]:

    dict_1 = {
        key: value
            for key, value in input.items()
                if condition(key, value)
    }

    dict_2 = {
        key: value
            for key, value in input.items()
                if not condition(key, value)
    }

    return (dict_1, dict_2)
```

Which would then be used with a `lambda`, like so:

```
(dict_1, dict_2) = \
    dict_partition(map, lambda key, value: key < 3)
```

This test case demonstrates that it works.

```
from .dict_partition import dict_partition

def test_dict_partition():

    input = {
        1: 'one',
        2: 'two',
        3: 'three',
        4: 'four',
        5: 'five'
    }

    (dict_1, dict_2) = dict_partition(input, lambda key, value: key < 3)

    dict_1_expected = {
        1: 'one',
        2: 'two'
    }

    dict_2_expected = {
        3: 'three',
        4: 'four',
        5: 'five'
    }

    assert dict_1 == dict_1_expected, 'dict_1 fail test case'
    assert dict_2 == dict_2_expected, 'dict_2 fail test case'
```

But pehaps there is some better solution which doesn't require us to write our own helper function to do it?

Comment: Nothing wrong with helper functions -- the thing that's a smell to this for me is not that you have a helper function, but that it calls the condition twice per item.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes I agree, that's also not great